# GCC inline asm NOP loop not being unrolled at compile time

Tags: assembly, gcc, inline-assembly, loop-unrolling, no-op

Venturing out of my usual VC++ realm into the world of GCC (via MINGW32). Trying to create a Windows PE that consists largely of NOPs, ala:

```
for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    asm("nop");
}
```

But either I'm using the wrong syntax or the compiler is optimising through them because those NOPs don't survive the compilation process.

I'm using the -O0 flag, otherwise defaults. Any ideas on how I can coax the compiler into leaving the NOPs intact?

Comment: Maybe `-O0` is the problem? Loops are usually inlined by optimizer. Try looking for a parameter for that.

Comment: It's not. I started without it. And I've looked through the MAN - no dice. -O0 should disable optimisations, by the literal definition.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why a delay loop? Under most circumstances I would classify this as *"avoid at all expense".* Mind you, I don't know the first thing about Windows PE.

Comment: I'm using it as padding to make a great big target for injecting some code into the executable.

Comment: Ah...fair enough. Not a delay at all, just a big block of nothing much. Makes sense.

Comment: "for" doesn't mean that the inner expressions will be duplicated N times in the code. Loop does mean that the expressions should be executed N times. You should probably use repeating macros for this to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you expecting it to unroll the loop in to 1000 `nop`s?  I did a quick test with `gcc` and I don't see the (one) `nop` disappear:

```
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        .p2align 4,,7
.L2:
#APP
        nop
#NO_APP
        addl    $1, %eax
        cmpl    $1000, %eax
        jne     .L2
```

With `gcc -S -O3 -funroll-all-loops` I see it unroll the loop 8 times (thus 8 `nop`) but I think if you want 1000 it's going to be easiest to do:

```
#define NOP10() asm("nop;nop;nop;nop;nop;nop;nop;nop;nop;nop")
```

And then use `NOP10(); ...`

Comment: Fair enough. That'd be a yes. Don't usually play with inline ASM in general.

Comment: how about asm("db 1000 dup (90h)") ?

Answer (score 9):

A convenient way to get 1000 inline `nop`s is to use the [`.rept` directive](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Rept.html#Rept) of the GNU assembler:

```
void thousand_nops(void) {
    asm(".rept 1000 ; nop ; .endr");
}
```

[Try on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/nn48b8).

Answer (score 3):

[This recent question about looping to 1000 without conditionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568645/printing-1-to-1000-without-loop-or-conditionals) resulted in a clever answer using template recursion which can actually be used to produce your 1000 `nop` function without repeating `asm("nop")` at all.  There are some caveats:  If you don't get the compiler to inline the function you will end up with a 1000-deep recursive stack of individual `nop` functions.  Also, `gcc`'s default template depth limit is 500 so you must specify a higher limit explicitly (see below, though you could simply avoid exceeding `nop<500>()`).

```
// compile time recursion
template<int N> inline void nop()
{
    nop<N-1>();
    asm("nop");
}

template<> inline void nop<0>() { }

void nops()
{
    nop<1000>();
}
```

Compiled with:

```
 g++ -O2 -ftemplate-depth=1000 ctr.c
```

Answer (score 1):

in addition to [the answer by @BenJackson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4575633/5980430), it can recurse with way less depth by (binary) division.

```cpp
template<unsigned int N> inline void nop()
{
    nop<N/2>();
    nop<N/2>();
    nop<N-2*(N/2)>();
}

template<> inline void nop<0>() { }
template<> inline void nop<1>() { asm("nop"); }
```