# Printing 1 to 1000 without loop or conditionals

Tags: c++, c, printf

**Task**: Print numbers from 1 to 1000 without using any loop or conditional statements. Don't just write the `printf()` or `cout` statement 1000 times.

How would you do that using C or C++?

Comment: So.... you question is *how do i do this*?

Comment: The obvious answer is to use 500 calls to `printf` and print two numbers each time, no?

Comment: I'm not a C or C++ guy but I'm assuming the answer is recursive.

Comment: Found a dupe : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044033/display-numbers-from-1-to-100-without-loops-or-conditions/

Tagged Java though.

Comment: printf("numbers from 1 to 1000");

Comment: `:?` isn't a conditional _statement_ (it's an expression)...

Comment: Sounds like a CompSci homework question. :-)

Comment: @Chris: `:?` is a "confused" face on some forum software.

Comment: Who votes it to be EXACT duplicate? The other question is about java, and it has different answers! The two languages are different!

Comment: I could understand no loops but why on earth no conditionals!? Theres no true way to do this without conditionals (unless its 1 to infinity) but i know it can be done without loops -edit- maybe templates as its compile time. Also i dont consider function calls as a loop (even if its recursion. Its just a jump/functional call).

Comment: lol this is not an exact duplicate of that java question. reopening...

Comment: Note that this is answered in the duplicate question for C++ here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044033/display-numbers-from-1-to-100-without-loops-or-conditions/2046685#2046685

Comment: @Yishai: that someone answered a wrong question there doesn't make this question a duplicate.

Comment: I'd relish the opportunity to question the interviewer about what real insights into my skills and ability he/she was getting out of asking this question, especially since I'd already know that I wouldn't want to work there.

Comment: The interview your chance to shine. Tell them "Without loops or conditionals? Child's play. I can do it without a computer!" Then pull out pen and notepad. They may give you a confused look, but just explain that if you can't count on built in language constructs, you really can't assume anything.

Comment: -1 Because its duplicated and nonsense. Also kind of offtopic I think it fits better in programmers.stackchange or as an example to Code Golf and Programming Puzzles beta

Comment: If instead of C/C++ you were asked to do this in assembly language, with equivalent constraints, it would be impossible. So why are you not allowed to do things that your compiler will make your code do anyways?

Comment: From my point of view *"Solve this puzzle with one more constraint than the last time it was posted"* question are unwanted, because they admit *"Solve the same puzzle with still another constraint"* and so on *ad nauseum*. To be sure the constructor solution is neat and understanding it means you know something about OO languages, but pone question on the matter is enough.

Comment: @dmckee: "Print 1 to 1000 without doing so."

Comment: Personally, I think there were several answers that had clever, interesting solutions. I also think that while this could easily be an awful interview question, there could be good value in it, as long as the interviewer is really looking not so much for a completely well-formed solution as looking for whether the interviewee considered approaches that indicate a knowledge of TMP or using constructs in unusual ways. I think it would be bad if this were used this as a pure 'got-it-right/wrong' question, but if it were used as the starting point of a discussion, I could see a lot of value.

Comment: `printf("42");` or `"00101010"` or `"0x2A"` or `"6*9"` or `"54"`.

Comment: Why are you people determined to close this one?

Comment: As someone who has interviewed many times and considered the "add a constraint" questions, there is definitely value to these questions. (a) You want to see how the interviewee deals with changes to the spec (b) see how the interviewee tries to find different approaches (c) weed out people who don't have any clue at all. Basically, the point in these questions is not the final answer, but the thought process. Another advantage of such simple questions is that they can weed out people who knew the question and said they'd never heard it before. I don't like to hire people who lie to me.

Comment: Continuing my previous comment, I've hired many people who didn't solve the problems, and rejected many who did. A single question is never the basis for such a decision.

Comment: @James Or you could just call printf 999 times, and use one of them to print two numbers.

Comment: People still equate conditional expressions with conditional statements. How nice.

Comment: Discussion on [proggit](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/ev2fc/printing_1_to_1000_without_loop_or_conditionals/).

Comment: If they want developers who program like that, their codebase is going to be a bear to maintain.

Comment: I'm just curious why this post got *91* +1's (and counting)? It's interesting, but is it really *that* interesting?!

Comment: Most programmers do count from zero.

Comment: The question is lame, but the answers are awesome.

Comment: Don't understand, people could grant bounty in a community wiki?

Comment: I think that the main goal of an interview question like this is to see if someone is capable of solving not just a complex problem, but also that they'll solve problems even if they're not that interesting.  I wouldn't want to hire someone who wouldn't work on a project they weren't interested in.  On the other hand, the problem with a question like this is that it could attract people who would rather spend their time solving puzzles instead of just getting the job done.

Comment: Beware, digits 0, 4, 6, 8 and 9 somewhat loop *per se*.

Comment: @Benoit I would add that 1 is a loop beheld from a side. Maybe other digits are just some twisted loops looked from some funny angle =:P

Answer (score 784, accepted):

Compile time recursion! :P

```
#include <iostream>
template<int N>
struct NumberGeneration{
  static void out(std::ostream& os)
  {
    NumberGeneration<N-1>::out(os);
    os << N << std::endl;
  }
};
template<>
struct NumberGeneration<1>{
  static void out(std::ostream& os)
  {
    os << 1 << std::endl;
  }
};
int main(){
   NumberGeneration<1000>::out(std::cout);
}
```

Comment: You know, that would make sense. But it's a weird question to ask if what they want to know is if the guy knows that templates are Turing complete.

Comment: You can make it shorter with function templates. Also I know two more solutions to this question, unfortunately the question is closed now :(

Comment: @ybungalobill : But people are voting to reopen. [I dont like function templates :(]

Comment: Right you are, I missed the fact that the recursion comes before printing, more elegant than mine.

Comment: @Prasoon : Is that guaranteed to work?  I think, no. I mean, what if instantiation depth exceeds at some point?

Comment: @Nawaz it will (does) produce a compile time error unless you modify the instantiation depth via command line arguments

Comment: Can somebody explain to me how this works? pretty impressive.

Comment: You should use `<< '\n'` rather than `<< std::endl` to avoid unnecessary buffer flushes.  (Yes, this works correctly on systems that use DOS newlines.)

Comment: @Zack: Let's get real, we're printing 1,000 lines from a program written to deliberately avoid loops. Performance is not an issue.

Comment: Neat. And the best thing of all is that it will be obvious he got help with his homework. :-)

Comment: For those curious enough to compile this: in g++, set -ftemplate-depth-1000. The default template recursion maximum is 500.

Comment: This still uses conditionals: pattern matching is a glorified if.

Comment: @davidk01: The normal definitions of "loop" and "conditional" refer to operations that take place at runtime, not compile time, and this code is free of those.  The code produced by the compiler will be 100% free of `CMP` and conditional jump instructions.

Comment: @Tom: it could also be modified to insrement by two every time and output two numbers, then, for a default template recursion depth of 500, you won't need any special compiler flags. :)

Comment: @dreamlax: This is one of those cases where I wish we could down-vote comments. This is a template-meta program, it will be executed by the compiler, at compile-time. The run-time program resulting from that does nothing but print 1000 numbers, so the __performance of the output is actually all that matters__, simply because after compilation there's nothing left but output.

Comment: @davidk01: Of course it does. Unless you write 1000 individual output statements you can't avoid using some kind of loop construct.

Comment: @sbi: The restrictions imposed were that it need only print the numbers 1 to 1,000 without loops or conditionals, it did not mention anything about the speed at which the program does it or how many stream flushes it is allowed. Using `'\n'` instead of `std::endl` isn't really all that useful.

Comment: @gath: It's a template-meta program with a mixed-in function call. The important thing is the recursive template instantiation. Note that each `NumberGeneration<N>` will instantiate `NumberGeneration<N-1>` (& calls its output function). This would be done until the compiler explodes, except the specialization `NumberGeneration<1>` doesn't instantiate any further template and so stops the recursion. Basically, template specialization is used for a compile-time `if`. [This famous article](http://erdani.com/publications/traits.html) by Alexandrescu explains the basics of this technique in detail.

Comment: @dreamlax: Of course the question didn't say anything about speed requirements. But _if_ we're talking about speed, the output is all that matters, because, at run-time, this program won't do anything but output. I agree with @Zack, Prasoon should have used `'\n'`, for the reason given by Zack. Thoughtlessly using `std::endl` is a common habit I see very often. I once had a coworker who spent days trying to find why a program's output speed was bad, until I pointed at the many `std::endl` calls. Replacing them sped up the app by a factor of ~6-8. I have paid close attention to them since.

Comment: @sbi: You're caring far too much about performance for such a useless application (not to mention risking premature optimisation). In fact, I even bothered to benchmark both and there was absolutely no measurable difference in execution time (both averaged roughly 20ms after about 40 runs each).

Comment: @dreamlax: It's just one of those things I have learned from experience over the years: use `'\n'` unless you really want to flush, use `++i` unless you actually need the former value of `i`, pass by `const` reference unless you have a good reason not to... When developers stop thinking about these (or never even start), they will, sooner or later, run into a problem where this matters, only they didn't even know there's spots where it might matter.

Comment: @sonicoder : Furthermore SO is a place for interesting things. For example read this : http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/a-new-name-for-stack-overflow-with-surprise-ending/

Comment: @Beh Tou Cheh : I knew you were fishy. Your account got suspended, why?

Comment: @sbi I know on Linux systems that it will flush on '\n' anyway, so there's really no functional difference between std::endl and '\n'. std::endl is just guaranteed to flush, and it's operating system dependent if '\n' flushes. A majority of the time, there is no difference.

Comment: @Jonathan: I'd be surprised if that's indeed the case, but I wouldn't rule it out. Even if it is true, though, the question didn't ask for a specific platform, so a good solution would be as good as possible on any platform.

Comment: @sbi I think I read it in another thread, but apparently '\n' will flush the buffer if the output is to something interactive. So '\n' will always flush for stdout (if stdout goes to a terminal), but it won't always flush if sent to a file. So they're the same if you output to a terminal, but different if it's a file.

Comment: @Jonathan: I think what you're referring to is the _tying_ of streams. `std::cout` is _tied_ to `std::cin` so that, before `std::cin` awaits user input `std::cout` will be flushed. I haven't looked closely into any implementations of that, but I think it's just that: any _input_ operation will trigger the flushing of the output.

Comment: @Jonathan: bit pedantic, but `'\n'` vs `endl` is about the C++ library flushing it's buffers, so you're presumably describing GCC behaviour rather than Linux's.  FWIW, my expectations (as a predominantly GCC/Linux developer) are that '\n' triggers flushing for `std::cerr` but not `std::cout`.  I agree with others who've said Prasoon's code should use `'\n'`... it's just sloppy and misleading as is, uselessly begging the question "why's it flushing - is there something else going on here?".

Comment: Surely the template specialisations are conditionals :)

Comment: I don't understand the first `NumberGeneration<N - 1>::out(os);` call above the `os << N..` call. Won't that make infinite recursion until N is 1. But how can it print if it's being called *above* the `os << N..` line??

Comment: @0x499602D2 Read up on recursion. It's not an *infinite* recursion since it stops at 1. And then it prints out 1. Then the one that called 1 prints two... then the one that called that prints 3... until we get back to the original (1000, in this case) and it prints 1000.

Comment: Just write a function *int print(int n)* which prints the number and then returns *n>0 && print(n-1)*.

Answer (score 1194):

This one actually compiles to assembly that doesn't have any conditionals:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(int j) {
  printf("%d\n", j);
  (&main + (&exit - &main)*(j/1000))(j+1);
}
```

---

Edit: Added '&' so it will consider the address hence evading the pointer errors.

This version of the above in standard C, since it doesn't rely on arithmetic on function pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f(int j)
{
    static void (*const ft[2])(int) = { f, exit };

    printf("%d\n", j);
    ft[j/1000](j + 1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    f(1);
}
```

Comment: Great solution. If it exited with status code 0 it would be perfect. I still upvoted it though... IDEA: replace (++j) with (++j * (1 - (j / 1001)) and it will exit with status code 0 :D

Comment: Yep, I originally implemented it that way. But the brevity of this solution was too irresistible.

Comment: Well, the code in this answer is obviously neither C nor C++, so this is fine only if we scrap the requirement. Then any answer may qualify because a hypothetical compiler might just produce the required program from any input.

Comment: Marvelous! I think it needs a little tweak: the order of evaluation of the j and the ++j in the last line is undefined (right?). I'd suggest:   printf("%d\n", j++); (main + (exit - main)*(j/1001))(j);

Comment: On second thought, just change ++j to j+1.

Comment: @PP, that's quite lengthy to explain, but basically, `j` is initially `1` because it's actually `argc`, which is `1` if the program is called without arguments. Then, `j/1000` is `0` until `j` becomes `1000`, after which it's `1`. `(exit - main)` is, of course, the difference between the addresses of `exit()` and `main()`. That means `(main + (exit - main)*(j/1000))` is `main()` until `j` becomes `1000`, after which it becomes `exit()`. The end result is that `main()` is called when the program starts, then calls itself recursively 999 times while incrementing `j`, then calls `exit()`. Whew :)

Comment: This is one of the most amazing abuses of C I have ever seen. But will it work on all platforms?

Comment: @Qwertie: You should read the international obfuscated C entries! Anyhow, some compilers might get pedantic about the prototype for main.

Comment: @eq - What am I missing? This compiles and runs just fine.

Comment: @Mark: this is non standard signature of main, you're disallowed to call main recursively, and the result of subtracting function pointers is undefined.

Comment: I've [tried](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568645/printing-1-to-1000-without-loop-or-conditionals/4765553#4765553) to adapt this routine to make it more universal and standard. Surprisingly, it just works.

Comment: @martin: nice, but the double ampersand operator is a GCC specific thing I think (not that my solution was fully portable)

Comment: @Bill Yes, you're right, it's not so "standard". Meanwhile I have updated my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568645/printing-1-to-1000-without-loop-or-conditionals/4765553#4765553) with another example :)

Comment: @martin: oddly enough, typeof is a GNU extension too, I think. Nice solution though.

Comment: Yeah, yeah, it's not strictly legal C++ code for the reasons @ybungalobill gives, but I have to +1 for sheer insanity and the fact that it does compile and work on a few platforms.  There are times when the correct response to "But it's not standard!" is "Who cares!" :)

Comment: Very clever! By the way, it IS possible that argc is 0 on some platforms when no commandline arguments are passed. I've never seen this in real life though, so bleh.

Comment: I'm with @ybungalobill here that you are not allowed to do this, but had to upvote nevertheless for its sheer madness. `:)`

Comment: Is actually wrong in C++ (maybe in C too, not sure). Stndard does allow only int main (int, char**) and int main() as valid entry points.

Comment: @ybungalobill : I don't see any reason not to subtract function pointers, any hint ?

Comment: @Ben: because the standard doesn't define what it means. I'm not sure if it allows it at all.

Comment: @ybungalobill: You're right, it doesn't allow it - the operands to the subtraction operator are either both arithmetic types; both pointers to compatible object types; or the left is an pointer to an object type and right is an integer type.  Pointers to functions are not pointers to object types (and neither are pointers to `void`).

Comment: @Sriram: Adding the `&` makes no difference to the legality of the code.

Comment: @caf: Moreover, the result is defined only if both pointers point to the same array (I don't remember the exact formulation).

Comment: @caf the '&' actually makes no difference to the semantics but hopefully evades some pointer errors. At least in my case, I was using tcc for trying out the code and adding the '&' made it run.

Answer (score 544):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int i = 0;
p()    { printf("%d\n", ++i); }
a()    { p();p();p();p();p(); }
b()    { a();a();a();a();a(); }
c()    { b();b();b();b();b(); }
main() { c();c();c();c();c();c();c();c(); return 0; }
```

I'm surprised nobody seems to have posted this -- I thought it was the most obvious way. `1000 = 5*5*5*8.`

Comment: People have posted this. The other versions pass the number to print instead of using a global, but it's essentially the same solution.

Comment: @Chris, they use the same logic expressed in macros or templates, blowing up the code size, right? You might as well generate the output string itself instead of a thousand printfs.

Comment: Oh yeah, I see Keith's answer does generate the whole string, cool. :) I missed that.

Comment: Well, nice effort, but rather odd that you didn't decompose 8 into 2*2*2 and thus use the unique prime factorisation

Answer (score 298):

Looks like it doesn't need to use loops

```
printf("1 10 11 100 101 110 111 1000\n");
```

Comment: one might argue that using `copy` is cheating

Comment: @Johannes actually I'm pretty sure `printf` has a loop :p

Comment: @litb:  Note I didn't say that "using `copy` **is** cheating"

Comment: @John : copying *is* cheating. do you doubt it? :P

Comment: @John i removed the "copy". only disturbs teh binary fun :)

Comment: @Johannes : why? it was good, atleast for learning purpose. In fact, that made me to give you upvote. :D. Please undo that, so that others can also learn something new, apart from having fun!

Comment: @Nawaz this way we have a C and a C++ answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568645/printing-1-to-1000-without-loop-or-conditionals/4587147#4587147 for the C++ bitset version. Cheers!

Comment: on a scale from 1 to 10, whats the chance I'm using binary?

Answer (score 270):

Here are three solutions that I know. The second might be argued though.

```
// compile time recursion
template<int N> void f1()
{ 
    f1<N-1>(); 
    cout << N << '\n'; 
}

template<> void f1<1>() 
{ 
    cout << 1 << '\n'; 
}

// short circuiting (not a conditional statement)
void f2(int N)
{ 
    N && (f2(N-1), cout << N << '\n');
}

// constructors!
struct A {
    A() {
        static int N = 1;
        cout << N++ << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    f1<1000>();
    f2(1000);
    delete[] new A[1000]; // (3)
    A data[1000]; // (4) added by Martin York
}
```

[ *Edit:* (1) and (4) can be used for compile time constants only, (2) and (3) can be used for runtime expressions too — *end edit.* ]

Comment: constructor one is cool. I'll mention i seen a java question where they have an array of 1000 and do arr[param] = val which will throw when it gets to 1000 and is caught at the end of main().

Comment: (4) can be used for runtime values too under modern compilers which support C99 extensions in C++ mode. Come on, it's 2010, let's not be afraid of VLAs :)

Comment: Also, I'd argue about a short-circuit not being a conditional... Not a statement, true, but a conditional expression, I'd say. Provided we define a conditional expression as "something which yields conditional jumps in assembler".

Comment: Question that hit me when reading the constructor one: Does the standard mandate that each item in the array be constructed in sequence? It would matter if the constructor had side effects. I'm sure every sane compiler implements it as a 0->1000 loop but I wonder if you could still be compliant and loop backwards...

Comment: @Joseph - The constructor one shouldn't be affected by what order the individual objects are initiated, but it is a good question.

Comment: @Joseph this is defined by 12.6/3 (C++03). Initialization is done in subscription order.

Comment: @Joseph: And they're destructed in reverse order too, so you could use a destructor just as easily :)

Comment: But the && is essential a conditional: a short form of x ? y : false. A true AND will evaluate both sides.

Answer (score 263):

I'm not writing the printf statement 1000 times!

```
printf("1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n11\n12\n13\n14\n15\n16\n17\n18\n19\n20\n21\n22\n23\n24\n25\n26\n27\n28\n29\n30\n31\n32\n33\n34\n35\n36\n37\n38\n39\n40\n41\n42\n43\n44\n45\n46\n47\n48\n49\n50\n51\n52\n53\n54\n55\n56\n57\n58\n59\n60\n61\n62\n63\n64\n65\n66\n67\n68\n69\n70\n71\n72\n73\n74\n75\n76\n77\n78\n79\n80\n81\n82\n83\n84\n85\n86\n87\n88\n89\n90\n91\n92\n93\n94\n95\n96\n97\n98\n99\n100\n101\n102\n103\n104\n105\n106\n107\n108\n109\n110\n111\n112\n113\n114\n115\n116\n117\n118\n119\n120\n121\n122\n123\n124\n125\n126\n127\n128\n129\n130\n131\n132\n133\n134\n135\n136\n137\n138\n139\n140\n141\n142\n143\n144\n145\n146\n147\n148\n149\n150\n151\n152\n153\n154\n155\n156\n157\n158\n159\n160\n161\n162\n163\n164\n165\n166\n167\n168\n169\n170\n171\n172\n173\n174\n175\n176\n177\n178\n179\n180\n181\n182\n183\n184\n185\n186\n187\n188\n189\n190\n191\n192\n193\n194\n195\n196\n197\n198\n199\n200\n201\n202\n203\n204\n205\n206\n207\n208\n209\n210\n211\n212\n213\n214\n215\n216\n217\n218\n219\n220\n221\n222\n223\n224\n225\n226\n227\n228\n229\n230\n231\n232\n233\n234\n235\n236\n237\n238\n239\n240\n241\n242\n243\n244\n245\n246\n247\n248\n249\n250\n251\n252\n253\n254\n255\n256\n257\n258\n259\n260\n261\n262\n263\n264\n265\n266\n267\n268\n269\n270\n271\n272\n273\n274\n275\n276\n277\n278\n279\n280\n281\n282\n283\n284\n285\n286\n287\n288\n289\n290\n291\n292\n293\n294\n295\n296\n297\n298\n299\n300\n301\n302\n303\n304\n305\n306\n307\n308\n309\n310\n311\n312\n313\n314\n315\n316\n317\n318\n319\n320\n321\n322\n323\n324\n325\n326\n327\n328\n329\n330\n331\n332\n333\n334\n335\n336\n337\n338\n339\n340\n341\n342\n343\n344\n345\n346\n347\n348\n349\n350\n351\n352\n353\n354\n355\n356\n357\n358\n359\n360\n361\n362\n363\n364\n365\n366\n367\n368\n369\n370\n371\n372\n373\n374\n375\n376\n377\n378\n379\n380\n381\n382\n383\n384\n385\n386\n387\n388\n389\n390\n391\n392\n393\n394\n395\n396\n397\n398\n399\n400\n401\n402\n403\n404\n405\n406\n407\n408\n409\n410\n411\n412\n413\n414\n415\n416\n417\n418\n419\n420\n421\n422\n423\n424\n425\n426\n427\n428\n429\n430\n431\n432\n433\n434\n435\n436\n437\n438\n439\n440\n441\n442\n443\n444\n445\n446\n447\n448\n449\n450\n451\n452\n453\n454\n455\n456\n457\n458\n459\n460\n461\n462\n463\n464\n465\n466\n467\n468\n469\n470\n471\n472\n473\n474\n475\n476\n477\n478\n479\n480\n481\n482\n483\n484\n485\n486\n487\n488\n489\n490\n491\n492\n493\n494\n495\n496\n497\n498\n499\n500\n501\n502\n503\n504\n505\n506\n507\n508\n509\n510\n511\n512\n513\n514\n515\n516\n517\n518\n519\n520\n521\n522\n523\n524\n525\n526\n527\n528\n529\n530\n531\n532\n533\n534\n535\n536\n537\n538\n539\n540\n541\n542\n543\n544\n545\n546\n547\n548\n549\n550\n551\n552\n553\n554\n555\n556\n557\n558\n559\n560\n561\n562\n563\n564\n565\n566\n567\n568\n569\n570\n571\n572\n573\n574\n575\n576\n577\n578\n579\n580\n581\n582\n583\n584\n585\n586\n587\n588\n589\n590\n591\n592\n593\n594\n595\n596\n597\n598\n599\n600\n601\n602\n603\n604\n605\n606\n607\n608\n609\n610\n611\n612\n613\n614\n615\n616\n617\n618\n619\n620\n621\n622\n623\n624\n625\n626\n627\n628\n629\n630\n631\n632\n633\n634\n635\n636\n637\n638\n639\n640\n641\n642\n643\n644\n645\n646\n647\n648\n649\n650\n651\n652\n653\n654\n655\n656\n657\n658\n659\n660\n661\n662\n663\n664\n665\n666\n667\n668\n669\n670\n671\n672\n673\n674\n675\n676\n677\n678\n679\n680\n681\n682\n683\n684\n685\n686\n687\n688\n689\n690\n691\n692\n693\n694\n695\n696\n697\n698\n699\n700\n701\n702\n703\n704\n705\n706\n707\n708\n709\n710\n711\n712\n713\n714\n715\n716\n717\n718\n719\n720\n721\n722\n723\n724\n725\n726\n727\n728\n729\n730\n731\n732\n733\n734\n735\n736\n737\n738\n739\n740\n741\n742\n743\n744\n745\n746\n747\n748\n749\n750\n751\n752\n753\n754\n755\n756\n757\n758\n759\n760\n761\n762\n763\n764\n765\n766\n767\n768\n769\n770\n771\n772\n773\n774\n775\n776\n777\n778\n779\n780\n781\n782\n783\n784\n785\n786\n787\n788\n789\n790\n791\n792\n793\n794\n795\n796\n797\n798\n799\n800\n801\n802\n803\n804\n805\n806\n807\n808\n809\n810\n811\n812\n813\n814\n815\n816\n817\n818\n819\n820\n821\n822\n823\n824\n825\n826\n827\n828\n829\n830\n831\n832\n833\n834\n835\n836\n837\n838\n839\n840\n841\n842\n843\n844\n845\n846\n847\n848\n849\n850\n851\n852\n853\n854\n855\n856\n857\n858\n859\n860\n861\n862\n863\n864\n865\n866\n867\n868\n869\n870\n871\n872\n873\n874\n875\n876\n877\n878\n879\n880\n881\n882\n883\n884\n885\n886\n887\n888\n889\n890\n891\n892\n893\n894\n895\n896\n897\n898\n899\n900\n901\n902\n903\n904\n905\n906\n907\n908\n909\n910\n911\n912\n913\n914\n915\n916\n917\n918\n919\n920\n921\n922\n923\n924\n925\n926\n927\n928\n929\n930\n931\n932\n933\n934\n935\n936\n937\n938\n939\n940\n941\n942\n943\n944\n945\n946\n947\n948\n949\n950\n951\n952\n953\n954\n955\n956\n957\n958\n959\n960\n961\n962\n963\n964\n965\n966\n967\n968\n969\n970\n971\n972\n973\n974\n975\n976\n977\n978\n979\n980\n981\n982\n983\n984\n985\n986\n987\n988\n989\n990\n991\n992\n993\n994\n995\n996\n997\n998\n999\n1000\n");
```

You're welcome ;)

Comment: I hope you wrote a program to generate that line.

Comment: open("1000.c",'w').write('printf("%s");' % ("\n".join([str(x) for x in xrange(1,1000)])))

Comment: I hope that the program you wrote to generate that line didn't contain loop!

Comment: If you add the closing double quote, this is my favorite answer.

Comment: A Vim macro would do the job quickly.

Comment: Not only is this the fastest solution, it is also the most correct, as any good compiler should compile down to something similar to a giant printf.

Comment: A bit of Perl generates it in a fancy way: `$r='printf("'; for (1..1000) { $r.="$_\\n" } $r.='");'; print $r;`

Comment: This is why I love ruby :) `print %{printf("#{[*1..1000].join('\n')}");}`

Answer (score 212):

```
printf("%d\n", 2);
printf("%d\n", 3);
```

It doesn't print *all* the numbers, but it does "Print numbers from 1 to 1000."  Ambiguous question for the win! :)

Comment: my favorite after 'printf("numbers from 1 to 1000")' - silly questions require silly answers.

Comment: this is awesome. +1 for taking advantage of the ambiguity in the question. haha

Comment: Edited; in no way, shape, or form did this code `print "Print numbers from 1 to 1000."` - ambiguous question for the win, inaccurate descriptions suck :)

Comment: Wow, there's been a bit of vandalism on this question's answers lately. Something tells me we should upgrade that lock to a historical lock.

Answer (score 172):

Trigger a fatal error! Here's the file, countup.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 1000
int boom;
int foo(n) {
    boom = 1 / (MAX-n+1);
    printf("%d\n", n);
    foo(n+1);
}
int main() {
    foo(1);
}
```

Compile, then execute on a shell prompt:

```
$ ./countup
1
2
3
...
996
997
998
999
1000
Floating point exception
$
```

This does indeed print the numbers from 1 to 1000, without any loops or conditionals!

Comment: you should call fflush(stdout); after each printf()... When a program crashes it's not guaranteed that the output buffer will be printed on screen.

Comment: @zakk: That's not strictly necessary - by default stdout is line buffered, so the `\n` will be enough to flush the output.

Comment: stdout is line buffered _if it can be determined to be an interactive device_ , otherwise it's fully buffered. If the professor redirects stdout to a file for automated checking, you will fail :-)

Comment: danger of stackoverflow (for example in an embedded enviroment)

Answer (score 166):

Using system commands:

```
system("/usr/bin/seq 1000");
```

Comment: High chance `/usr/bin/seq` uses a loop internally. :)

Comment: @jokester: you mean, because Solaris/BSD doesn't have a `seq` utility (in the default setup)?   <grin/>

Comment: I hate to say this (well, no I don't), but there's a bug in your solution.  It doesn't print out the right set of numbers. :)

Here's the fix: ``system("/bin/echo {1..1000}");``

If only you had written the unit test first...

Comment: Some bright dude decided to change my answer, so that's not my mistake.

Answer (score 100):

Untested, but should be vanilla standard C:

```
void yesprint(int i);
void noprint(int i);

typedef void(*fnPtr)(int);
fnPtr dispatch[] = { noprint, yesprint };

void yesprint(int i) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
    dispatch[i < 1000](i + 1);
}

void noprint(int i) { /* do nothing. */ }

int main() {
    yesprint(1);
}
```

Comment: @Prasoon: It's a relation.

Comment: requirement is "no conditionals" (if, switch, etc).  not "no conditions"

Comment: Anyway, "i < 1000" is a condition, but I like this solution.

Comment: `<` is not a condition. It's a relational operator. `if` / `else` is a conditional statement. `?:` is a conditional operator. `<` is just an operator that returns a boolean value. It's probably a single machine instruction with no jumps or anything.

Comment: Just a comment - the array declaration should be `fnPtr dispatch[] = { noprint, yesprint };` since your `[i <= 1000]` would be `1` if true (and would call `noprint` in your existing code). Additionally, your expression only needs to be `[i < 1000]` since on `999`, it would call `yesprint` with `i+1 == 1000`. Other than that, +1 for your approach.

Comment: Nice, but recursive, which is the biggest drawback here.

Comment: Nice idea, but the way you wrote it won't compile nor work. Here is a corrected version : http://ideone.com/AeglZ

Comment: @Martin: The standard says that `true`, when converted to an integer, is `1`.  So whatever system you've seen where it wasn't, wasn't C and wasn't C++.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Darn showing my age (Updated since I last read the C standard).

Comment: @Martin: Dude, even C89 says <quote> Each of the operators < (less than), > (greater than), <= (less than or equal to), and >= (greater than or equal to) shall yield 1 if the specified relation is true and 0 if it is false. The result has type int.</quote>  And `&&`, `||`, and `!` follow the same rule.   It gets worse: the 1974 version did too: [The value of ``expression relation expression'' is 1 if the relation is true, and 0 if false](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/bwk-tutor.html#relational).  I suspect you're thinking of another language.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I could be wrong. But I remember that the only guarantees we had were `#define FALSE 0` and `#define TRUE (!FALSE)`. Even back then we had to write portable code (shesh for the airforce) and these two systems actually had different truth values (System A 1: System B 255) (now it could have been one was non standard C (people were not as strict about it back then (but I am sure I looked it up (maybe I just messed up)). I suppose a tutorial from Bell is as close to the standard as we are getting from those days.

Comment: @Martin: My copy of K&R (2nd Ed) says that relational operators return 0 or 1 by definition. You can rely on those int values.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: On x86, it's 3 instructions: `cmpl`, `setle`, and `movzbl`.  x86-64 is that plus a `cltq`.  PowerPC is 2 instructions: `cmpwi` and `crnot`.

Comment: @Adam - My bad. Still no jumps, unless I know far less about assembly than I thought I did.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: Correct, there are no jumps in those instruction sequences.  It's still fast, even though it's 2-4 instructions, because there are no branch mispredictions.

Comment: Actually I lied, the PowerPC sequence is 4 instructions: `cmpwi`, `crnot`, `mfcr`, and `rlwinm`.

Comment: If using `i < 1000` is contentious, you can use another indirection. Add `static int jeez[1001]; jeez[1000] = 1;` and replace `i < 1000` with `1 - jeez[i]`.  (Static arrays are initialised to zero.)

Comment: Pedants, the requirement is 'no conditional statements', not 'no conditional operators'. Also, assembly is not C nor C++, and vice versa.

Comment: `1 - i / 1000`. No comparisons!

Comment: There's nothing contentious about `i < 1000`. It's no more conditional than `-`: there's no flow control or short-circuiting involved.

Answer (score 96):

A bit boring compared to others here, but probably what they're looking for.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int val) {
    --val && f(val);
    return printf( "%d\n", val+1);
}

void main(void) {
    f(1000);
}
```

Comment: Made it shorter. set i=1 outside of main and then inside of main: printf("%d\n", 11 - i) && --i && main(i);

Comment: @Jens Schauder: By taking advantage of lazy `&&` evaluation in the first line of `f()`.

Comment: This isn't boring, it's simple. If you can do the same thing with a short function as you can with a huge mess of template magic, then you should do it with the function :)

Comment: The && is a conditional. A mathematical AND will evaluate both sides (like the Java & and the Ada "AND" does). && will evaluate the 2nd operator only **if** (here it is) the first is true. Or other example: In Ada it short-circuits operator is called "OR THEN" - using THEN to indicate the conditional aspect. Sorry, you could have just as well used the ? : operator.

Comment: No need to apologize. && is a comparison operator. The ternary operator is a conditional.

Answer (score 71):

The task never specified that the program must terminate after 1000.

```
void f(int n){
   printf("%d\n",n);
   f(n+1);
}

int main(){
   f(1);
}
```

(*Can be shortened to this if you run ./a.out with no extra params*)

```
void main(int n) {
   printf("%d\n", n);
   main(n+1);
}
```

Comment: It does not stop at 1000, though.  It just keeps going.

Comment: Can be shortened only if you scrap the requirement of C or C++. Then any "program" will do, because a theoretical compiler could generate the program you want (from any input).

Comment: @eq Again, this compiles and runs just fine…

Comment: That has to be my favorite (the short version). Simple and clear.

Comment: As an afterthought: we can even evade _apparent_ math. If we employ `rand()`, we shall print all of them numbers from 1 to 1000. **Eventually** =:P

Comment: @pooh: Not necessarily, since rand() has a chance of repeating after certain sequence, and that sequence might be not fall in the solution set for this problem

Answer (score 71):

Easy as pie! :P

```
#include <iostream>

static int current = 1;

struct print
{
    print() { std::cout << current++ << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    print numbers [1000];
}
```

Comment: you might want to do "static int current = 0" otherwise will print from 2 to 1001.

Comment: i changed ++current to current++

Answer (score 65):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define Out(i)       printf("%d\n", i++);
#define REP(N)       N N N N N N N N N N
#define Out1000(i)   REP(REP(REP(Out(i))));
void main()
{
 int i = 1;
 Out1000(i);
}
```

Comment: Ummmm. Macros.  It's whats for dinner.

Answer (score 42):

We can launch 1000 threads, each printing one of the numbers. Install [OpenMPI](http://www.open-mpi.org/), compile using `mpicxx -o 1000 1000.cpp` and run using `mpirun -np 1000 ./1000`. You will probably need to increase your descriptor limit using `limit` or `ulimit`. Note that this will be rather slow, unless you have loads of cores!

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <mpi.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  MPI::Init(argc, argv);
  cout << MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank() + 1 << endl;
  MPI::Finalize();
}
```

Of course, the numbers won't necessarily be printed in order, but the question doesn't require them to be ordered.

Comment: Implicit loop in the library? But +1 anyway for a new approach.

Comment: @Chris Don't most solutions have a hidden loop somewhere?

Comment: I suppose, if you take the "loops in the compiler" approach. Since (outside of a possible loop over the arguments in `MPI::Init()`) I can't imagine any loops in the actual binary of your 1000.cpp program, I gave you a +1, even though there are certainly loops running when you execute it.

Answer (score 40):

With plain C:

```
#include<stdio.h>

/* prints number  i */ 
void print1(int i) {
    printf("%d\n",i);
}

/* prints 10 numbers starting from i */ 
void print10(int i) {
    print1(i);
    print1(i+1);
    print1(i+2);
    print1(i+3);
    print1(i+4);
    print1(i+5);
    print1(i+6);
    print1(i+7);
    print1(i+8);
    print1(i+9);
}

/* prints 100 numbers starting from i */ 
void print100(int i) {
    print10(i);
    print10(i+10);
    print10(i+20);
    print10(i+30);
    print10(i+40);
    print10(i+50);
    print10(i+60);
    print10(i+70);
    print10(i+80);
    print10(i+90);
}

/* prints 1000 numbers starting from i */ 
void print1000(int i) {
    print100(i);
    print100(i+100);
    print100(i+200);
    print100(i+300);
    print100(i+400);
    print100(i+500);
    print100(i+600);
    print100(i+700);
    print100(i+800);
    print100(i+900);
}


int main() {
        print1000(1);
        return 0;
}
```

Of course, you can implement the same idea for other bases (2: print2 print4 print8 ...) but the number 1000 here suggested base 10. You can also reduce a little the number of lines adding intermediate functions: `print2() print10() print20() print100() print200() print1000()` and other equivalent alternatives.

Comment: Why does the number 1000 suggest base 10? In any positional notation with base `B`, 1000 is a perfectly valid number and always equals `B^3`.

Comment: I just meant that, given how the number is represented in base 10, the factorization "10x10x10" suggested itself, but that other alternatives are possible. I guess I should have said "factorization" instead of "base"

Answer (score 34):

Just use std::copy() with a special iterator.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

struct number_iterator
{
    typedef std::input_iterator_tag iterator_category;
    typedef int                     value_type;
    typedef std::size_t             difference_type;
    typedef int*                    pointer;
    typedef int&                    reference;

    number_iterator(int v): value(v)                {}
    bool operator != (number_iterator const& rhs)   { return value != rhs.value;}
    number_iterator operator++()                    { ++value; return *this;}
    int operator*()                                 { return value; }
    int value;
};



int main()
{
    std::copy(number_iterator(1), 
              number_iterator(1001), 
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Comment: I think your code starts from 0. Also agree with Chris, the question as I saw it years ago was stated as "without any libraries except for IO". yet +1 :)

Comment: @Chris Lutz: The implementation of copy is undefined. I may even use template code as above (you just don;t know). So you can't say it uses a loop because we don't know.

Comment: Actually, my nit pick wouldn't be the implicit loop in `std::copy` so much as the implicit conditional in the `operator !=()`.  Regardless, it's a clever take on processing a range, and clever approaches is what I look for in response to questions like this.

Comment: implementation specific is undefined

Comment: @selvaiyyamperumal: Not sure exactly what you are talking about. But if you are talking about behavior then the standard disagrees with you. "Implementation Defined behavior" means it is well defined but must be explicitly documented by the implementation. "Undefined Behavior" means anything can happen.

Answer (score 33):

Function pointer (ab)use. No preprocessor magic to increase output. ANSI C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i=1;

void x10( void (*f)() ){
    f(); f(); f(); f(); f();
    f(); f(); f(); f(); f();
}

void I(){printf("%i ", i++);}
void D(){ x10( I ); }
void C(){ x10( D ); }
void M(){ x10( C ); }

int main(){
    M();
}
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking of.  A previous person said that 5*5*5*8=1000.  I thought that it was funny he was missing the obvious 10^3.  Nice solution!

Answer (score 32):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int num() { static int i = 1; return i++; }
int main() { generate_n(ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\n"), 1000, num); }
```

Answer (score 30):

Ugly C answer (unrolled for only one stack frame per power of 10):

```
#define f5(i) f(i);f(i+j);f(i+j*2);f(i+j*3);f(i+j*4)
void f10(void(*f)(int), int i, int j){f5(i);f5(i+j*5);}
void p1(int i){printf("%d,",i);}
#define px(x) void p##x##0(int i){f10(p##x, i, x);}
px(1); px(10); px(100);

void main()
{
  p1000(1);
}
```

Comment: all things alright, but why "void main()"? bad habits seldom go? :P

Comment: @Nawaz: Because this is secretly a Windows GUI app, so it doesn't matter.  I only called it "main" because I was thinking about lobsters and have terrible spelling.

Answer (score 29):

Stack overflow:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void print_line(int i)
{   
 printf("%d\n", i); 
 print_line(i+1);
}   

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
 //get up near the stack limit
 char tmp[ 8388608 - 32 * 1000 - 196 * 32 ];
 print_line(1);
}
```

This is for an 8MB stack. Each function invocation appears to take about 32 bytes (hence the 32 * 1000). But then when I ran it I only got to 804 (hence the 196 * 32; perhaps the C runtime has other parts in the stack that you have to deduct also).

Answer (score 25):

Fun with function pointers (none of that new-fangled TMP needed):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>


#define MSB(typ) ((sizeof(typ) * CHAR_BIT) - 1)

void done(int x, int y);
void display(int x, int y);

void (*funcs[])(int,int)  = {
    done,
    display
};

void done(int x, int y)
{
    exit(0);
}

void display(int x, int limit)
{
    printf( "%d\n", x);
    funcs[(((unsigned int)(x-limit)) >> MSB(int)) & 1](x+1, limit);
}


int main()
{
    display(1, 1000);
    return 0;
}
```

As a side note: I took the prohibition against conditionals to extend to logical and relational operators as well.  If you allow logical negation, the recursive call can be simplified to:

```
funcs[!!(limit-1)](x+1, limit-1);
```

Comment: i like the way you've got it with the bit shift. but with your simplification afterthought, what does the double bang do? its bitwise or logical? im lost and google got me going around in circles `funcs[!!(limit-1)](x+1, limit-1); `

Comment: I'd rather have a single `!` and switch the function pointer array elements, but I don't know if that will play well with your other craziness.

Comment: @Chris: I agree completely - but I didn't consider using logical/relation operators until after posting, and I figured a single-line patch would be more appropriate. Besides, it fits in a little better with the whole obfuscated feel of the problem.

Answer (score 24):

I feel this answer will be very simple and easy to understand.

```
int print1000(int num=1)
{
    printf("%d\n", num);

    // it will check first the num is less than 1000. 
    // If yes then call recursive function to print
    return num<1000 && print1000(++num); 
}

int main()
{
    print1000();
    return 0;        
}
```

Comment: Your answer uses conditional statements, which are forbidden according to the question.

Comment: conditional statements are if else etc. I just used a logical operation!! Hpe it is clear!

Comment: Even in your comments you wrote "If yes then call recursive function to print". A conditional written in an unobvious way is still a conditional. The num default is also a conditional.

Answer (score 23):

I missed all the fun, all the good C++ answers have already been posted !

This is the weirdest thing I could come up with, I wouldn't bet it's legal C99 though :p

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i = 1;
int main(int argc, char *argv[printf("%d\n", i++)])
{
  return (i <= 1000) && main(argc, argv);
}
```

---

Another one, with a *little* cheating :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define ECHO_COUNT(z, n, unused) n+1
#define FORMAT_STRING(z, n, unused) "%d\n"

int main()
{
    printf(BOOST_PP_REPEAT(1000, FORMAT_STRING, ~), BOOST_PP_ENUM(LOOP_CNT, ECHO_COUNT, ~));
}
```

---

Last idea, same cheat :

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
#define ECHO_COUNT(z, n, unused) BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(BOOST_PP_INC(n))"\n"
    std::cout << BOOST_PP_REPEAT(1000, ECHO_COUNT, ~) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Calling `main` results in undefined behavior as I remember.

Comment: It's perfectly legal C. @ybungalobill: You must be thinking of C++, where calling main() is specifically disallowed.

Comment: @Michael: Maybe, I'm not very familiar with C.

Comment: I think using Boost implies C++.  Regardless, kudos for the Boost.PP solution.

Comment: @me22: We were referring to the first solution (before answer was edited to include the other two alternatives).

Comment: The logical operators `&&` and `||` would likely fall under "conditionals" since they short-circuit (as would `?:`).

Answer (score 22):

Easy as pie:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf(argv[0]);
}
```

method of execution:

```
printer.exe "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30;31;32;33;34;35;36;37;38;39;40;41;42;43;44;45;46;47;48;49;50;51;52;53;54;55;56;57;58;59;60;61;62;63;64;65;66;67;68;69;70;71;72;73;74;75;76;77;78;79;80;81;82;83;84;85;86;87;88;89;90;91;92;93;94;95;96;97;98;99;100;101;102;103;104;105;106;107;108;109;110;111;112;113;114;115;116;117;118;119;120;121;122;123;124;125;126;127;128;129;130;131;132;133;134;135;136;137;138;139;140;141;142;143;144;145;146;147;148;149;150;151;152;153;154;155;156;157;158;159;160;161;162;163;164;165;166;167;168;169;170;171;172;173;174;175;176;177;178;179;180;181;182;183;184;185;186;187;188;189;190;191;192;193;194;195;196;197;198;199;200;201;202;203;204;205;206;207;208;209;210;211;212;213;214;215;216;217;218;219;220;221;222;223;224;225;226;227;228;229;230;231;232;233;234;235;236;237;238;239;240;241;242;243;244;245;246;247;248;249;250;251;252;253;254;255;256;257;258;259;260;261;262;263;264;265;266;267;268;269;270;271;272;273;274;275;276;277;278;279;280;281;282;283;284;285;286;287;288;289;290;291;292;293;294;295;296;297;298;299;300;301;302;303;304;305;306;307;308;309;310;311;312;313;314;315;316;317;318;319;320;321;322;323;324;325;326;327;328;329;330;331;332;333;334;335;336;337;338;339;340;341;342;343;344;345;346;347;348;349;350;351;352;353;354;355;356;357;358;359;360;361;362;363;364;365;366;367;368;369;370;371;372;373;374;375;376;377;378;379;380;381;382;383;384;385;386;387;388;389;390;391;392;393;394;395;396;397;398;399;400;401;402;403;404;405;406;407;408;409;410;411;412;413;414;415;416;417;418;419;420;421;422;423;424;425;426;427;428;429;430;431;432;433;434;435;436;437;438;439;440;441;442;443;444;445;446;447;448;449;450;451;452;453;454;455;456;457;458;459;460;461;462;463;464;465;466;467;468;469;470;471;472;473;474;475;476;477;478;479;480;481;482;483;484;485;486;487;488;489;490;491;492;493;494;495;496;497;498;499;500;501;502;503;504;505;506;507;508;509;510;511;512;513;514;515;516;517;518;519;520;521;522;523;524;525;526;527;528;529;530;531;532;533;534;535;536;537;538;539;540;541;542;543;544;545;546;547;548;549;550;551;552;553;554;555;556;557;558;559;560;561;562;563;564;565;566;567;568;569;570;571;572;573;574;575;576;577;578;579;580;581;582;583;584;585;586;587;588;589;590;591;592;593;594;595;596;597;598;599;600;601;602;603;604;605;606;607;608;609;610;611;612;613;614;615;616;617;618;619;620;621;622;623;624;625;626;627;628;629;630;631;632;633;634;635;636;637;638;639;640;641;642;643;644;645;646;647;648;649;650;651;652;653;654;655;656;657;658;659;660;661;662;663;664;665;666;667;668;669;670;671;672;673;674;675;676;677;678;679;680;681;682;683;684;685;686;687;688;689;690;691;692;693;694;695;696;697;698;699;700;701;702;703;704;705;706;707;708;709;710;711;712;713;714;715;716;717;718;719;720;721;722;723;724;725;726;727;728;729;730;731;732;733;734;735;736;737;738;739;740;741;742;743;744;745;746;747;748;749;750;751;752;753;754;755;756;757;758;759;760;761;762;763;764;765;766;767;768;769;770;771;772;773;774;775;776;777;778;779;780;781;782;783;784;785;786;787;788;789;790;791;792;793;794;795;796;797;798;799;800;801;802;803;804;805;806;807;808;809;810;811;812;813;814;815;816;817;818;819;820;821;822;823;824;825;826;827;828;829;830;831;832;833;834;835;836;837;838;839;840;841;842;843;844;845;846;847;848;849;850;851;852;853;854;855;856;857;858;859;860;861;862;863;864;865;866;867;868;869;870;871;872;873;874;875;876;877;878;879;880;881;882;883;884;885;886;887;888;889;890;891;892;893;894;895;896;897;898;899;900;901;902;903;904;905;906;907;908;909;910;911;912;913;914;915;916;917;918;919;920;921;922;923;924;925;926;927;928;929;930;931;932;933;934;935;936;937;938;939;940;941;942;943;944;945;946;947;948;949;950;951;952;953;954;955;956;957;958;959;960;961;962;963;964;965;966;967;968;969;970;971;972;973;974;975;976;977;978;979;980;981;982;983;984;985;986;987;988;989;990;991;992;993;994;995;996;997;998;999;1000"
```

The specification does not say that the sequence must be generated **inside** the code :)

Answer (score 18):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Printer
{
public:
 Printer() { cout << ++i_ << "\n"; }
private:
 static unsigned i_;
};

unsigned Printer::i_ = 0;

int main()
{
 Printer p[1000];
}
```

Answer (score 15):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void nothing(int);
void next(int);
void (*dispatch[2])(int) = {next, nothing};

void nothing(int x) { }
void next(int x)
{
    printf("%i\n", x);
    dispatch[x/1000](x+1);
}

int main()
{
    next(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

More preprocessor abuse:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define A1(x,y) #x #y "0\n" #x #y "1\n" #x #y "2\n" #x #y "3\n" #x #y "4\n" #x #y "5\n" #x #y "6\n" #x #y "7\n" #x #y "8\n" #x #y "9\n"
#define A2(x) A1(x,1) A1(x,2) A1(x,3) A1(x,4) A1(x,5) A1(x,6) A1(x,7) A1(x,8) A1(x,9)
#define A3(x) A1(x,0) A2(x)
#define A4 A3(1) A3(2) A3(3) A3(4) A3(5) A3(6) A3(7) A3(8) A3(9)
#define A5 "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n" A2() A4 "1000\n"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf(A5);
    return 0;
}
```

I feel so dirty; I think I'll go shower now.

Comment: Can you call `A2()` without an argument like that?

Comment: I was curious about that myself. It works properly with GCC, but I don't know if it's well-defined behavior.

Comment: Well-defined in C99, don't remember what C89 said, does cause trouble with at least some versions of MSVC if memory serves.

Answer (score 15):

If POSIX solutions are accepted:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static void die(int sig) {
    exit(0);
}

static void wakeup(int sig) {
    static int counter = 1;
    struct itimerval timer;
    float i = 1000 / (1000 - counter);

    printf("%d\n", counter++);

    timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
    timer.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    timer.it_value.tv_usec = i; /* Avoid code elimination */
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timer, 0);
}

int main() {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    signal(SIGFPE, die);
    signal(SIGALRM, wakeup);
    wakeup(0);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); /* Deadlock, YAY! */
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Since there is no restriction on bugs..

```
int i=1; int main() { int j=i/(i-1001); printf("%d\n", i++); main(); }
```

Or even better(?),

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

int i=1;
int foo() { int j=i/(i-1001); printf("%d\n", i++); foo(); }

int main()
{
        signal(SIGFPE, exit);
        foo();
}
```

Comment: You should avoid compiler optimisations then, to keep the otherwise unused j.

Comment: He only need to add `volatile` to the declaration of `j`

Answer (score 12):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*fp) (int);

void stop(int i)
{
   printf("\n");
}

void next(int i);

fp options[2] = { next, stop };

void next(int i)
{
   printf("%d ", i);
   options[i/1000](++i);
}

int main(void)
{
   next(1);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works. I think it is pretty vanilla C. I could use exit instead of stop. But basically I need to call something when it reaches 1000. See my other solution in this thread for an example which calls exit.

Answer (score 11):

Using pointer arithmetic we can use automatic array initialization to 0 to our advantage.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func();
typedef void (*fpa)();
fpa fparray[1002] = { 0 };

int x = 1;
void func() {
 printf("%i\n", x++);
 ((long)fparray[x] + &func)();
}

void end() { return; }

int main() {
 fparray[1001] = (fpa)(&end - &func);
 func();
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

For C++ lovers

```
int main() {
  std::stringstream iss;
  iss << std::bitset<32>(0x12345678);
  std::copy(std::istream_iterator< std::bitset<4> >(iss), 
            std::istream_iterator< std::bitset<4> >(),
            std::ostream_iterator< std::bitset<4> >(std::cout, "\n")); 
}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
template <int To, int From = 1>
struct printer {
    static void print() {
        cout << From << endl; 
        printer<To, From + 1>::print();
    }
};    

template <int Done>
struct printer<Done, Done> {
     static void print() {
          cout << Done << endl;
     }
};

int main() 
{
     printer<1000>::print();
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Preprocessor abuse!

```
#include <stdio.h>

void p(int x) { printf("%d\n", x); }

#define P5(x) p(x); p(x+1); p(x+2); p(x+3); p(x+4);
#define P25(x) P5(x) P5(x+5) P5(x+10) P5(x+15) P5(x+20)
#define P125(x) P25(x) P25(x+50) P25(x+75) P25(x+100)
#define P500(x) P125(x) P125(x+125) P125(x+250) P125(x+375)

int main(void)
{
  P500(1) P500(501)
  return 0;
}
```

The preprocessed program (see it with `gcc -E input.c`) is amusing.

Answer (score 9):

Nobody said it shouldn't segfault afterwards, right?

Note: this works correctly on my 64-bit Mac OS X system. For other systems, you will need to change the args to setrlimit and the size of spacechew accordingly. ;-)

(I shouldn't need to include this, but just in case: this is clearly not an example of good programming practice. It does, however, have the advantage that it makes use of the name of this site.)

```
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void recurse(int n)
{
    printf("%d\n", n);
    recurse(n + 1);
}

int main()
{
    struct rlimit rlp;
    char spacechew[4200];

    getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rlp);
    rlp.rlim_cur = rlp.rlim_max = 40960;
    setrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rlp);

    recurse(1);
    return 0; /* optimistically */
}
```

Answer (score 9):

OpenMP version (non-ordered of course):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(1000)
    {           
#pragma omp critical
        {
            std::cout << omp_get_thread_num() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(Does not work with VS2010 OpenMP runtime (restricted to 64 threads), works however on linux with, e.g., the Intel compiler)

Here's an ordered version too:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i = 1;
  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(1000)
  #pragma omp critical
    printf("%d ", i++);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [OpenMPI answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568645/printing-1-to-1000-without-loop-or-conditionals/4580366#4580366)

Comment: Yep, but OpenMPI version should be running using processes

Answer (score 9):

This only uses O(log N) stack and uses McCarthy evaluation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation as its recursion condition.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int printN(int n) {
  printf("%d\n", n);
  return 1;
}

int print_range(int low, int high) {
  return ((low+1==high) && (printN(low)) ||
      (print_range(low,(low+high)/2) && print_range((low+high)/2, high)));
}

int main() {
  print_range(1,1001);
}
```

Comment: @davka: To stop people from writing pointless comments like "wow".

Comment: @Tomalak: :) "wow" here means "I am really impressed with this original approach", but is just much more concise

Answer (score 8):

A C++ variant of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044033/display-numbers-from-1-to-100-without-loops-or-conditions/2044090#2044090) from the supposed duplicate:

```
void print(vector<int> &v, int ind)
{
    v.at(ind);
    std::cout << ++ind << std::endl;
    try
    {
        print(v, ind);
    }
    catch(std::out_of_range &e)
    {
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v(1000);
    print(v, 0);
}
```

Comment: why passing the vector *by value*?

Comment: @Nawaz, just an oversight, fixed now.

Comment: You don't modify the vector so use a const reference?

Answer (score 8):

I've reformulated the great routine proposed by [Bill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568645/printing-1-to-1000-without-loop-or-conditionals/4583502#4583502) to make it more universal:

```
void printMe () 
{
    int i = 1;
    startPrintMe:
    printf ("%d\n", i);
    void *labelPtr = &&startPrintMe + (&&exitPrintMe - &&startPrintMe) * (i++ / 1000);
    goto *labelPtr;
    exitPrintMe:
}
```

**UPDATE:** The second approach needs 2 functions:

```
void exitMe(){}
void printMe ()
{
    static int i = 1; // or 1001
    i = i * !!(1001 - i) + !(1001 - i); // makes function reusable
    printf ("%d\n", i);
    (typeof(void (*)())[]){printMe, exitMe} [!(1000-i++)](); // :)
}
```

For both cases you can initiate printing by simply calling

```
printMe();
```

Has been tested for GCC 4.2.

Answer (score 7):

```
template <int remaining>
void print(int v) {
 printf("%d\n", v);
 print<remaining-1>(v+1);
}

template <>
void print<0>(int v) {
}

print<1000>(1);
```

Answer (score 7):

With macros!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define x001(a) a
#define x002(a) x001(a);x001(a)
#define x004(a) x002(a);x002(a)
#define x008(a) x004(a);x004(a)
#define x010(a) x008(a);x008(a)
#define x020(a) x010(a);x010(a)
#define x040(a) x020(a);x020(a)
#define x080(a) x040(a);x040(a)
#define x100(a) x080(a);x080(a)
#define x200(a) x100(a);x100(a)
#define x3e8(a) x200(a);x100(a);x080(a);x040(a);x020(a);x008(a)
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i = 0;
  x3e8(printf("%d\n", ++i));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @mossplix: Sure!  `x001(a)` is a macro that performs the given action once.  `x002(a)` performs `x001(a)` twice, so it performs the action twice.  `x004(a)` performs `x002(a)` twice, so it performs the given action 4 times.  Things go on doubling until we define `x3e8(a)`, which performs the action 1000 times (3e8 in hex).  The action given is `printf("%d\n", ++i)`, which increments i and then prints it.  So when we pass it to `x3e8()`, since macros aren't pass-by-value (unlike functions, which are), the action is repeated 1000 times, printing all the numbers from 1 to 1000.

Answer (score 7):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int b=1;
int printS(){    
    printf("%d\n",b);
    b++;
    (1001-b) && printS();
}
int main(){printS();}
```

Comment: because the post is locked, i'll put this here:

compile this .c file to a.out and run with "./a.out 0".  It calls itself, recursively, with python:

`#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char oh_god_no[50];
  if(atoi(argv[1])==1000) return 0;
  sprintf(oh_god_no,"python -c \"import os; print %d; os.system('./a.out %d\')\"",atoi(argv[1])+1,atoi(argv[1])+1);
  system(oh_god_no); }`

Answer (score 6):

It's also possible to do it with plain dynamic dispatch (works in Java too):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class U {
  public:
  virtual U* a(U* x) = 0; 
  virtual void p(int i) = 0;
  static U* t(U* x) { return x->a(x->a(x->a(x))); }
};

class S : public U {
  public:
  U* h;
  S(U* h) : h(h) {}
  virtual U* a(U* x) { return new S(new S(new S(h->a(x)))); }
  virtual void p(int i) { cout << i << endl; h->p(i+1); }
};

class Z : public U {
  public:
  virtual U* a(U* x) { return x; }
  virtual void p(int i) {}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  U::t(U::t(U::t(new S(new Z()))))->p(1);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do it pretty simply using recursion and a forced error...

Also, pardon my horridly sloppy c++ code.

```
void print_number(uint number)
{
    try
    {
        print_number(number-1);
    }
    catch(int e) {}
    printf("%d", number+1);
}

void main()
{
    print_number(1001);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

How about another abnormal termination example. This time adjust stack size to run out at 1000 recursions.

```
int main(int c, char **v)
{
    static cnt=0;
    char fill[12524];
    printf("%d\n", cnt++);
    main(c,v);
}
```

On my machine it prints 1 to 1000

```
995
996
997
998
999
1000
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Ah yeah, the famous "Works on My Machine" Certification Program.

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by Orion_G's answer and reddit discussion; uses function pointers and binary arithmetic:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define b10 1023
#define b3 7

typedef void (*fp) (int,int);

int i = 0;
void print(int a, int b) { printf("%d\n",++i); }
void kick(int a, int b) { return; }

void rec(int,int);
fp r1[] = {print, rec} ,r2[] = {kick, rec};
void rec(int a, int b) {
  (r1[(b>>1)&1])(b10,b>>1);
  (r2[(a>>1)&1])(a>>1,b);
}

int main() {
  rec(b10,b3);
  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Using macro compaction:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define a printf("%d ",++i);
#define b a a a a a
#define c b b b b b
#define d c c c c c
#define e d d d d

int main ( void ) {
    int i = 0;
    e e
    return 0;
}
```

Or still better:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define a printf("%d ",++i);
#define r(x) x x x x x
#define b r(r(r(a a a a)))

int main ( void ) {
    int i = 0;
    b b
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[manglesky's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568645/printing-1-to-1000-without-loop-or-conditionals/4582309#4582309) is great, but not obfuscated enough. :-) So:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TEN(S) S S S S S S S S S S
int main() { int i = 1; TEN(TEN(TEN(printf("%d\n", i++);))) return 0; }
```

Answer (score 5):

After some tinkering I came up with this:

```
template<int n>
class Printer
{
public:
    Printer()
    {        
        std::cout << (n + 1) << std::endl;
        mNextPrinter.reset(new NextPrinter);
    }

private:
    typedef Printer<n + 1> NextPrinter;
    std::auto_ptr<NextPrinter> mNextPrinter;
};

template<>
class Printer<1000>
{
};

int main()
{
    Printer<0> p;
    return 0;
}
```

Later @ybungalobill's submission inspired me to this much simpler version:

```
struct NumberPrinter
{
    NumberPrinter()
    {
        static int fNumber = 1;
        std::cout << fNumber++ << std::endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    NumberPrinter n[1000];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think that the struct constructor solution is just beautiful, great idea.

Answer (score 5):

My little contribution to this fabulous set of answers (it returns zero) :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int a)
{
    return a ^ 1001 && printf("%d\n", main(a+1)) , a-1;
}
```

Comma operator is FTW \o/

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT 2:**

I removed undefined behaviors from code. Thanks to @sehe for notice.

No loops, recursions, conditionals and everything standard C ... (qsort abuse):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int numbers[51] = {0};

int comp(const void * a, const void * b){
    numbers[0]++;
    printf("%i\n", numbers[0]);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
  qsort(numbers+1,50,sizeof(int),comp);
  comp(NULL, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: why is `int numbers[0]` ok? I'd have expected that to be undefined behaviour in `++numbers[0]`? If you can explain why it should not be `int numbers[1];` I'd be much obliged

Comment: I believe that writing to array in out-of-bounds fashion is undefined behavior. So `++numbers[0]` is UB as well as sorting not existing 246 array elements with qsort is also UB. I just found empirically that when using `int numbers[1]` and `qsort(numbers+1,...` - output results in somewhat chaotic fashion.

Comment: By looking at second version and thinking why `int numbers[1]` and `qsort(numbers+2` works i came with idea that somewhere in the sorting process memory at address one-past array is overwritten and thus using `numbers[1]` and qsort(numbers+1)` or `numbers[0]` and qsort(numbers+0)` results in incorrect list. This is my best guess.

Comment: I must say I secretly enjoy how you state you _`reduced`_ the number of UB's by a _negative amount_. Cheers and thanks for explaining. I think (?) I _sort of_ understand. (pun intended)

Answer (score 4):

Don't know enough C(++) to write code, but you could use recursion instead of a loop. In order to avoid the condition you could use a datastructure which will throw an exception after the 1000th access. E.g. some kind of list with range checking where you increase/decrease the index on each recursion.

Judging from the comments there don't seem to be any rangechecking lists in C++?

Instead you could 1/n with n being a parameter to your recursive function, which gets reduced by 1 on each call. Start with 1000. The DivisionByZero Exception will stop your recursion

Comment: `range checking` that would require a conditional.

Comment: Unless you're going with compile time recursion like Prasoon Saurav's answer, a recursive function would still need a conditionnal statement to stop.

Comment: My C powers are weak; can you set an interrupt on integer overflow/underflow which breaks the program?

Comment: @Etienne de Martel, if you read, he says to avoid a conditional, use an Exception. Not sure how to do it in C++, but in Java it could be done easily. Create an array of size 1000 and use recursion. When an exception is caught return.

Comment: @Nicholas Exceptions also exist in C++.

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need anything more than basic string processing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

std::string r(std::string s, char a, char b)
{
    std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), a, b);
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s0 = " abc\n";
    std::string s1 = r(s0,'c','0')+r(s0,'c','1')+r(s0,'c','2')+r(s0,'c','3')+r(s0,'c','4')+r(s0,'c','5')+r(s0,'c','6')+r(s0,'c','7')+r(s0,'c','8')+r(s0,'c','9');
    std::string s2 = r(s1,'b','0')+r(s1,'b','1')+r(s1,'b','2')+r(s1,'b','3')+r(s1,'b','4')+r(s1,'b','5')+r(s1,'b','6')+r(s1,'b','7')+r(s1,'b','8')+r(s1,'b','9');
    std::string s3 = r(s2,'a','0')+r(s2,'a','1')+r(s2,'a','2')+r(s2,'a','3')+r(s2,'a','4')+r(s2,'a','5')+r(s2,'a','6')+r(s2,'a','7')+r(s2,'a','8')+r(s2,'a','9');
    std::cout << r(r(s1,'a',' '),'b',' ').substr(s0.size())
          << r(s2,'a',' ').substr(s0.size()*10)
          << s3.substr(s0.size()*100)
          << "1000\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Neither loop nor conditional Statements and at least it doesn't crash on my machine :). Using with some pointer magic we have...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*fp) (void *, int );

void end(fp* v, int i){
    printf("1000\n");
    return;
}

void print(fp *v, int i)
{
    printf("%d\n", 1000-i);
    v[i-1] = (fp)print;
    v[0] = (fp)end;
    (v[i-1])(v, i-1);

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fp v[1000];

    print(v, 1000);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I hate to break it, but recursion and looping are essentially the same thing at the machine level.

The difference is the use of a JMP/JCC versus a CALL instruction.  Both of which have roughly the same cycle times and flush the instruction pipeline.

My favorite trick for recursion was to hand-code a PUSH of a return address and use JMP to a function.  The function then behaves normally, and returns at the end, but to somewhere else.  This is really useful for parsing faster because it reduces instruction pipeline flushes.

The Original Poster was probably going for either a complete unroll, which the template guys worked out; or page memory into the terminal, if you know exactly where the terminal text is stored.  The latter requires alot of insight and is risky, but takes almost no computational power and the code is free of nastiness like 1000 printfs in succession.

Comment: Did you implement `COME FROM` for C?!

Comment: It is everything the same at machine level. But the OP was about not how to do it on machine level, but in C++. Otherwise, we can of course discuss why Haskell is there if everything is the same at the machine level.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print(int n)
{
    int q;

    printf("%d\n", n);
    q = 1000 / (1000 - n);
    print(n + 1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    print(1);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It will eventually stop :P

Answer (score 4):

There are plenty of abnormal exits due to stack overflows so far, but no heap ones yet, so here's my contribution:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
#define PAGE_SIZE 4096
void print_and_set(int i, int* s)
{
  *s = i;
  printf("%d\n", i);
  print_and_set(i + 1, s + 1);
}
void
sigsegv(int)
{
  fflush(stdout); exit(0);
}
int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int* mem = reinterpret_cast<int*>
    (reinterpret_cast<char*>(mmap(NULL, PAGE_SIZE * 2, PROT_WRITE,
                                  MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0)) +
     PAGE_SIZE - 1000 * sizeof(int));
  mprotect(mem + 1000, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_NONE);
  signal(SIGSEGV, sigsegv);
  print_and_set(1, mem);
}
```

Not very good practice, and no error checks (for obvious reasons) but I don't think that is the point of the question!

There are plenty of other abnormal termination options, of course, some of which are simpler: assert(), SIGFPE (I think someone did that one), and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Should work on any machine that doesn't like 0 / 0. You could replace this with a null pointer reference if you need to. The program can fail after printing 1 to 1000, right?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_1000(int i);
void print_1000(int i) {
    int j;
    printf("%d\n", i);
    j = 1000 - i;
    j = j / j;
    i++;
    print_1000(i);
}

int main() {
    print_1000(1);
}
```

Comment: nice answer. would have been good if it would not crash ecevtually.

Answer (score 4):

Using recursion, conditionals can be substituted using function pointer arithmetic:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // for: void exit(int CODE)

// function pointer
typedef void (*fptr)(int);

void next(int n)
{
        printf("%d\n", n);

        // pointer to next function to call
        fptr fp = (fptr)(((n != 0) * (unsigned int) next) +
                         ((n == 0) * (unsigned int) exit));

        // decrement and call either ``next'' or ``exit''
        fp(n-1);
}

int main()
{
        next(1000);
}
```

Note that there are no conditionals; `n!=0` and `n==0` are branchless operations.  (Though, we perform a branch in the tail call).

Answer (score 4):

Amazing how easy it becomes if you drop the "has to be in C or C++" requirement:

Unix shell:

```
echo {1..1000} | tr ' ' '\n'
```

or

```
yes | nl | awk '{print $1}' | head -1000
```

If you're running on a Unix variant that doesn't have the yes command, use some other process that generates at least 1000 lines:

```
find / 2> /dev/null | nl | awk '{print $1}' | head -1000
```

or

```
cat /dev/zero | uuencode - | nl | awk '{print $1}' | head -1000
```

or

```
head -1000 /etc/termcap | nl -s: | cut -d: -f1
```

Comment: Well, we just use system(), and voila! :)

Answer (score 4):

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <string.h>

        typedef void(*word)(int);

        word words[1024];

        void print(int i) {
                printf("%d\n", i);
                words[i+1](i+1);
        }

        void bye(int i) {
                exit(0);
        }

        int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
                words[0] = print;
                words[1] = print;
                memcpy(&words[2], &words[0], sizeof(word) * 2); // 0-3
                memcpy(&words[4], &words[0], sizeof(word) * 4); // 0-7
                memcpy(&words[8], &words[0], sizeof(word) * 8); // 0-15
                memcpy(&words[16], &words[0], sizeof(word) * 16); // 0-31
                memcpy(&words[32], &words[0], sizeof(word) * 32); // 0-63
                memcpy(&words[64], &words[0], sizeof(word) * 64); // 0-127
                memcpy(&words[128], &words[0], sizeof(word) * 128); // 0-255
                memcpy(&words[256], &words[0], sizeof(word) * 256); // 0-511
                memcpy(&words[512], &words[0], sizeof(word) * 512); // 0-1023
                words[1001] = bye;
                words[1](1);
        }
```

Comment: Inspired by Loeliger's Threaded Interpretive Languages, doesn't need an error to exit.

Answer (score 4):

Put the 1 to 1000 in a file "file"

```
int main()
{
    system("cat file");
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming, due to the nature of this question that extensions are not excluded?

Also, I'm surprised that so far no one used `goto`.

```
int main () {
    int i = 0;
    void * addr[1001] = { [0 ... 999] = &&again};
    addr[1000] = &&end;
again:
    printf("%d\n", i + 1);
    goto *addr[++i];
end:
    return 0;
}
```

Ok, so *technically* it is a loop - but it's no more a loop than all the recursive examples so far ;)

Answer (score 4):

I'm wondering if the interviewer garbled a different question: Calculate the **sum** of the numbers from 1 to 1000 (or from any n through m) without using a loop. It also teaches a good lesson about analyzing problems. Printing the #s from 1 through 1000s in C will always rely on tricks that you may not use in a production program (tail recursion in Main, side effects of how truthiness is calculated, or preproc and template tricks.)

That would be a good spot-check to see if you've had any sort of mathematical training, because that old story about Gauss and his solution would probably be well known to anyone with any sort of math training.

Answer (score 4):

Well, what do you think about

```
int main(void) {
    printf(" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8");
    return 0;
}
```

I bet that 1000 was in binary and
he was obviously checking the guy's CQ ( compSci Quotient)

Comment: its better until they don't question our IQ.. :P

Comment: This isn't that witty of an answer ;P, because you are writing the printf statement 1000 (8) times. Ok, not exactly, but same idea as if you did `printf("1 ... 1000");` which is against the rules.

Answer (score 4):

c++ exploiting RAII

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static int i = 1;
struct a
{
    a(){cout<<i++<<endl;}
    ~a(){cout<<i++<<endl;}
}obj[500];

int main(){return 0;}
```

C exploiting macros

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define c1000(x) c5(c5(c5(c4(c2(x))))) 
#define c5(x) c4(x) c1(x) //or x x x x x
#define c4(x) c2(c2(x))   //or x x x x
#define c2(x) c1(x) c1(x) //or x x
#define c1(x) x

int main(int i){c1000(printf("%d\n",i++);)return 0;}
```

Edit: One more, this one is simple

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define p10(x) x x x x x x x x x x
int main(int i){p10(p10(p10(printf("%d\n",i++);)))return 0;}
```

C exploiting recrusion

edit: this c code contains <= and ?: operators

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int i){return (i<=1000)?main(printf("%d\n",i++)*0 + i):0;}
```

Comment: 1) exploiting RAII 2) exploiting recursion.

Comment: Yeah but it's got conditionals in it

Comment: oh.. oops!.. wrote another one.. :P

Comment: RAII means more than having a constructor and destructor... it means a constructor that doesn't throw has successfully taken ownership of some resource.  You don't "own" `i` here, firstly it's static, and secondly other objects with overlapping lifetimes do exactly the same kind of access/updates.

Comment: I meant exploiting the the constructor and destructor calls during RAII+cleanup processes for the obj[500]

Answer (score 4):

This is standard C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("%d ", argc);
    (void) (argc <= 1000 && main(argc+1, 0));

    return 0;
}
```

If you call it without arguments, it will print the numbers from 1 to 1000. Notice that the && operator is not a "conditional statement" even though it serves the same purpose.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdexcept>

using namespace std;

int main(int arg)

{
    try

    {

        printf("%d\n",arg);
        int j=1/(arg-1000);
        main(arg+1);
    }

    catch(...)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int show(int i) {
   printf("%d\n",i);
   return( (i>=1000) || show(i+1));
}


int main(int argc,char **argv) {
   return show(1);
}
```

The || operator short-circuits the recursive call to show when i is >= 1000.

Comment: Ha! I came up with this solution and was going to post it just now. :)

Comment: i>=1000 is a conditional. Requirements not met.

Comment: @Sparkie `>=` is a relational operator, it is not a condition, that debate has happened here already, and other answers have used this same approach.

Comment: >= is not a conditional. But the || is a conditional. A mathematical OR will evaluate both sides (like the Java | and the Ada "OR" does).

|| will evaluate the 2nd operator only **if** (here it is) the first is false.

Or other example: In Ada it short-circuits operator is called "OR ELSE" - using ELSE to indicate the conditional aspect.

Sorry, you could have just as well used the ? : operator.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

void foo( int n )
{
 printf("%d\n", n);
 assert( n > 0 );
 foo(--n); 
}

int main()
{
 foo( 1000 );
 getchar();
}
```

Comment: assert is a conditional statement :/

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
printf("numbers from 1 to 1000\n");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your C compiler supports blocks then you can write the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ten(void (^b)(void)) { b();b();b();b();b();b();b();b();b();b(); }

int main() {
    __block int i = 0;
    ten(^{
        ten(^{
            ten(^{
                printf("%d\n", ++i);
            });
        });
    });
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the program is run in the usual way (./a.out) so that it has one argument, and ignoring the compiler type warnings then:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(int i) {
    static void (*cont[2])(int) = { main, exit };
    printf("%d\n", i);
    cont[i/1000](i+1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version that uses setjmp/longjmp, because someone had to do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

void print(int i) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
typedef void (*func_t)(int);

int main() {
    jmp_buf buf;
    func_t f[] = {print, exit};
    int i = setjmp(buf)+1;
    f[i/1001](i);
    longjmp(buf, i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sadly, setjmp is only guaranteed to work within a conditional construct; so it's precluded by the rules. +1 for stickin' it to the rules!

Comment: Holy mackerel, you're right! But yeah, I guess undefined behavior is cool in a nonconformist way.

Answer (score 3):

Despite all the brilliant code seen here, I think that the only real answer is that it can't be done.

Why? Simple. Every single answer is, in fact, looping.  Looping hidden as recursion is still looping.  One look at the assembly code reveals this fact.  Even reading and printing a text file with the numbers involves looping. Again, look at the machine code.  Typing 1000 printf statements also means looping because printf itself has loops within it.

Can't be done.

Comment: Look at my answer :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568645/printing-1-to-1000-without-loop-or-conditionals/6448479#6448479

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<int N>
void func()
{
        func<N-1>();
        cout << N << "\t";
}

template<>
void func<1>()
{
        cout << 1 << "\t";
}

int main()
{
        func<1000>();
        cout << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: It gives error  ` instantiated from 'void func() [with int N = 963]'`

Answer (score 3):

I've read through all of these answers, and mine's different from all the others. It is standard C and uses integer division to select function pointers from an array. Moreover it compiles and executes correctly with no warnings and even passes 'splint' with no warnings.

I was, of course inspired by many of the other answers here. Even so, mine's better.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int x(/*@unused@*/ const char * format, ...) { exit(0); }

static void p(int v, int e) {
    static int (*a[])(const char *, ...) = { printf, x };
    (void)a[v/(e+1)]("%d\n", v);
    p(v+1, e);
}

int main(void) {
    p(1, 1000);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
static n=1;
class number {
public:
    number () {
        std::cout << n++ << std::endl;
    }
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    number X[1000];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        print(1000);
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static bool print(int val)
    {
        try
        {
            print( ((val/val)*val) - 1);
            System.Console.WriteLine(val.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
system("/usr/bin/env echo {1..1000}");
```

Comment: Pretty much a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568645/printing-1-to-1000-without-loop-or-conditionals/4580500#4580500

Comment: Not exactly.  Seq isn't installed on many *nix systems.  OS X is one of them.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <boost/mpl/range_c.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  boost::mpl::for_each<boost::mpl::range_c<unsigned, 1, 1001> >(std::cout << boost::lambda::_1 << '\n');
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: @marcog: No, it is not. It is a compile time recursion which may unroll (code bloat!) to linear code when optimizing.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to see through all the solutions that have already been proposed, so maybe this is a duplicate.

I wanted to have something relatively simple just with pure C and not C++. It uses recursion, but contrary to other solutions that I have seen it only does recursion of logarithmic depth. The use of conditionals is avoided by a table lookup.

```
typedef void (*func)(unsigned, unsigned);
void printLeaf(unsigned, unsigned);
void printRecurse(unsigned, unsigned);


func call[2] = { printRecurse, printLeaf };

/* All array members that are not initialized 
   explicitly are implicitly initialized to 0 
   according to the standard. */
unsigned strat[1000] = { 0, 1 };


void printLeaf(unsigned start, unsigned len) {
  printf("%u\n", start);
}

void printRecurse(unsigned start, unsigned len) {
  unsigned half0 = len / 2;
  unsigned half1 = len - half0;
  call[strat[half0]](start, half0);
  call[strat[half1]](start + half0, half1);
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
  printRecurse(0, 1000);
}
```

This could even be done dynamically by using just a pointer. Relevant changes:

```
unsigned* strat = 0;

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
  strat = calloc(N, sizeof(*strat));
  strat[1] = 1;
  printRecurse(0, N);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**stand c++ concept, pass on gcc, vc**

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat 1.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int i = 1;
void print(int arg0)
{
    printf("%d ",i);
    *(&arg0 - 1) = (int)print;
    *(&arg0 - i/1000) = (int)exit;
    i++;
}
int main(void) {
    int a[1000];
    print(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Running it:

```
[root@localhost ~]# g++ 1.cpp -o 1
[root@localhost ~]# ./1

1 2 ... 1000
```

Answer (score 2):

As it is answer :)

`printf("numbers from 1 to 1000 without using any loop or conditional statements. Don't just write the printf() or cout statement 1000 times.");`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind leading zeros, then lets skip printf

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void l();
void n();
void (*c[3])() = {l, n, exit};
char *a;
void (*x)();
char b[] = "0000";
void run() { x(); run(); }
#define C(d,s,i,j,f) void d() { s;x = c[i]; a = j;f; }
C(l, puts(b), 1+(a<b), b+3,)
C(n, int v = *a - '0' + 1; *a = v%10 + '0', v/10, a-1,)
C(main,,1,b+3, run())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void (*f[2])(int);
static void p(int i)
{ 
    printf("%d\n", i);
}

static void e(int i)
{
    exit(0);
}

static void r(int i)
{ 
    f[(i-1)/1000](i);
    r(i+1);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    f[0] = p;
    f[1] = e;
    r(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a POSIX variant using signals:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void counter(int done)
{
        static int i;

        done = ++i / 1000;

        printf("%d\n", i);

        signal(SIGINT, (void (*)(int))(done * (int)SIG_DFL + (1-done) * (int)&counter));
        raise(SIGINT);
}

int main()
{
        signal(SIGINT, &counter);
        raise(SIGINT);

        return 0;
}
```

The interesting part is counter()'s call to signal(). Here, a new signal handler is installed: SIG_DFL if "done" is true, &counter otherwise.

To make this solution even more ridiculous, I used the signal handler's required int parameter to hold the result of a temporary computation. As a side-effect, the annoying "unused variable" warning disappears when compiling with gcc -W -Wall.

Answer (score 2):

Here are my 2 solutions. First is C# and the second in C:

C#:

```
const int limit = 1000;

Action<int>[] actions = new Action<int>[2];
actions[0] = (n) => { Console.WriteLine(n); };
actions[1] = (n) => { Console.WriteLine(n);  actions[Math.Sign(limit - n-1)](n + 1); };

actions[1](0);
```

C:

```
#define sign(x) (( x >> 31 ) | ( (unsigned int)( -x ) >> 31 ))

void (*actions[3])(int);

void Action0(int n)
{
    printf("%d", n);
}

void Action1(int n)
{
    int index;
    printf("%d\n", n);
    index = sign(998-n)+1;
    actions[index](++n);
}

void main()
{
    actions[0] = &Action0;
    actions[1] = 0; //Not used
    actions[2] = &Action1;

    actions[2](0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

a dirty code :s

used xor and array of function pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef void (*fn)(int);
int lst[1001];

void print (int n)
{
  printf ("%d ", n+1);
  go (n+1);
}

void go (int n)
{
  ((fn)(((long)print)^((long)lst[n])))(n);
}

int main ()
{
  lst[1000] = ((long)print)^((long)exit);
  go (0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(int i){printf("%d\n",i)&&i++<1000&&(*((int*)&i-1)-=5);}
```

another one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int i){return i<=1000&&printf("%d\n",i)&&main(++i);}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is too obvious and easy to follow, but this is standard C++, does not dump stack and runs in O(n) time using O(n) memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char** args) {
  vector<int> foo = vector<int>(1000);
  int terminator = 0;
 p:
  cout << terminator << endl; 
  try {
    foo.at(terminator++);
  } catch(...) {
    return 0;
  }
  goto p;
}
```

Comment: p: ... goto p; is a looping construct.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously requires Windows/Visual Studio... But it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

void print(int x)
{
    int y;

    printf("%d\n", x);
    __try
    {
        y = 1 / (x - 1000);
        print(x + 1);
    }
    __except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
    {
        return;
    }
}

void main()
{
    print(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple C version, terminates at 1000:

```
int print_stuff(int count) {
   printf("%d\n", count);
   return (count ^ 1000) && print_stuff(count+1);
 }

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   print_stuff(1);
   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
#define N 10    //10 or 1000, doesn't matter

class A{
public:
    A(){
        //cout << "A(): " << m_ << endl;    //uncomment to show the difference between gcc and Microsoft C++ compiler
    }
    A(const A&){
        ++m_;
        cout << m_ << endl;     
    }
private:
    static int m_;  //global counter
};

int A::m_(0);  //initialization

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //Creates a vector with N elements. Printing is from the copy constructor, 
    //which is called exactly N times.
    vector<A> v(N);  
    return 0;   
}
```

Implementation note:
With gcc: One "master" element is created by the default constructor.
Then the element is copied N times by the copy constructor.
With Microsoft C++ compiler: all the elements are created by default constructor
and then copied by the copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use compile-time recursion, then you probably also want to use divide & conquer to avoid hitting template depth limits:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int L, int U>
struct range
{
    enum {H = (L + U) / 2};
    static inline void f ()
    {
        range<L, H>::f ();
        range<H+1, U>::f ();
    }
};

template<int L>
struct range<L, L>
{
    static inline void f ()
    {
        std::cout << L << '\n';
    }
};

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    range<1, 1000>::f ();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { printf("numbers from 1 to 1000"); return 0; }
```

It's like that other riddle about english words that end in "gry", right?.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void (*f[2])(int v);

void p(int v) 
{ 
  printf("%d\n", v++); 
  f[(int)(floor(pow(v, v - 1000)))](v); 
}

void e(int v) 
{
  printf("%d\n", v);
}

int main(void)
{
  f[0] = p;
  f[1] = e;
  p(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript thrown in for fun. Includes an automatic stop at 1000:

```
var max = 1000;
var b = ["break"];
function increment(i) {
    var j = Math.abs(i - max);
    console.log(j);           
    b[(i/i) - 1].toString();
    i--;
    increment(i);    
}
increment(max);
```

Answer (score 1):

Note:

- please look forward to get results.
- that this program often bug.

Then

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#define sleep(x) Sleep(x*1000)
#endif

int main() {
  time_t c = time(NULL);
retry:
  sleep(1);
  std::cout << time(NULL)-c << std::endl;
goto retry;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to write the code but just the idea. How about to make a thread that print a number per second, and then another thread kill the first thread after 1000 seconds?

note: the first thread generate numbers by recursion.

Comment: Well, that thread would still have to print the numbers without using any loop or conditional statements, so that would only introduce an additional `one number per second` requirement.

Comment: ok. how about recursion. the timer is to terminate the program without conditional

Comment: How about the first thread being a little slow and failing to print everything before the other one kills it? Congratulations, you just introduced a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't suppose this is a "trick question" . . . "?:" isn't an conditional, it is an operator.

So use recursion and the ?: operator to detect the when to stop?

```
int recurse(i)
{
   printf("%d\n", i);
   int unused = i-1000?recurse(i+1):0;

}

recurse(1);
```

Or along a similar perverted line of thinking . . . the second clause in an "&" condition is only executed if the first value is true.  So recurse something like this:

```
i-1000 & recurse(i+1);
```

Perhaps the interviewer considers that an expression instead of a conditional.

Comment: It's already been commented many times that `?:` is counted as a conditional.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System()` to print 1 to 1000 (by **using DOS Command**)

```
 include <process.h>
 void main()
 {
     system("cmd.exe /c for /l %x in (1, 1, 1000) do echo %x" );
 }
```

Run **.exe(executable)** file of your program which displays 1 to 1000

NOTE: Tested in WINDOWS

Comment: @SLaks: I am not using any loop statement of C/C++, just passing arguments as string..

Answer (score 0):

i think these code works perfectly right and its easy to understand you can print any like 1 to 100 or 1 to the final range. just put it in i and transfer it to call function.

```
int main()
{
    int i=1;
    call(i,i);
}

void call(int i,int j)
{
    printf("%d",i);
    sleep(1); // to see the numbers for delay
    j /= (j-1000);

    j = ++i;

    call(i,j);
}
```

so when j equals 1000 it gets divide by zero and it directly exits the program thats my idea to print the numbers

or much simpler code..

```
int main()
{
    static int i = 1;
    static int j = 1;
    printf("%d", i);
    sleep(1);
    j = ++i;
    j /= (j-1000);
    main();
}
```

Comment: This code is so wrong (and that's not only due to the shitty formatting): Syntax error in the `call()` call in the first block, calling `main()` in the second block (you may not call `main()` inside your program).

Comment: it works theif master if you dont know how it does then just be idle dont say we are wrong u can make main() recursive in c but not in c++ see the output of that code

Comment: i dont know how people gone through it all without knowing the basic things like recursive main in c.without knowing the static storage class and thier work and the call function code works perfectly too. before downvoting my solution think it twice theif master

Comment: It might work, but that doesn't mean calling `main()` is allowed. For example you cannot assume that it cleans up properly after returning since usually a program terminates when `main()` returns.

Comment: i just gave a hint boss its an interview its a logical thing you need to show your not going apply it in your real code

Answer (score -6):

Recursion?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 1000

int i = 0;
void foo(void) {
    if(i <= 1000) {
         printf("%d", i);
         i++;
    }
}
int main (void) {
    foo();
}
```

Comment: This has already been done over and over. And this isn't even correct.

Answer (score -7):

you can use recursion .

like this:

```
void Print(int n)
{
  cout<<n<<" ";   
  if(n>1000)
     return
  else
     return Print(n+1)
}    

int main ()
{
  Print(1);
}
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the "or conditional statements" part.