# Print 1 to 100 with out loop and conditions in C

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Printing 1 to 1000 without loop or conditionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568645/printing-1-to-1000-without-loop-or-conditionals)

code to print 1 to 100 without using loops and conditions.

Comment: printf("1 to 100\n"); !

Comment: @ramshankar- Welcome to Stack Overflow!  From what I've gathered, you seem to already have the answer to this question, and that's great... I really like your solution.  As an FYI, this site is mostly for asking questions to which you yourself do not know the answer.  That way, the community can offer up answers that then get voted up and down by other readers.  If you do ask a question and then immediately post an answer, you'll be missing out on the opportunity to learn a lot from a very powerful brain trust!

Comment: @moderators: pl remove the question as its redundant one.

Comment: @ramshankar You can remove the question yourself!

Answer (score 2):

```
void print(){        
static int i;

printf("%d\n",++i);

}

void exitme(){ exit(1); }

int main(){

       void (*p[2])()={print,exitme};
       static int i;
       (p[i++/100])();
       main();
}
```