# How compile time recursion works?

Tags: c++, compile-time

I found a code here [Printing 1 to 1000 without loop or conditionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568645/printing-1-to-1000-without-loop-or-conditionals)

Can someone please explain how compile time recursion works, couldn't find it in google

```
// compile time recursion
template<int N> void f1()
{ 
    f1<N-1>(); 
    cout << N << '\n'; 
}

template<> void f1<1>() 
{ 
    cout << 1 << '\n'; 
}


int main()
{
    f1<1000>();
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Actually there is a trick, the specialization is a conditional, though there is no `if` keyword...

Comment: Is there a rule of thumb about much faster this is than run time recursion?

Comment: Whats the benefit of using this in place of regular recursion?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It repeatedly instantiates the `f1<N>` template with decreasing values for `N` (`f1<N>()` calls `f1<N-1>` and so on). The explicit specialization for `N==1` ends the recursion: as soon as `N` becomes 1, the compiler will pick the specialized function rather than the templated one.

`f1<1000>()` causes the compiler to instantiate `f1<N>` 999 times (not counting in the final call to `f1<1>`). This is the reason why it can take a while to compile code that makes heavy use of template meta-programming techniques.

The whole thing relies heavily on the compiler's optimization skills - ideally, it should remove the recursion (which only serves as hack to emulate a `for` loop using templates) completely.

Answer (score 2):

It works conceptually almost the same way as runtime recursion. `f1<1000>` calls `f1<999>` and then prints out 1000. `f1<999>` calls `f1<998>` and then prints out 999, etc. Once it gets to 1 the template specialization acts as the base case to abort the recursion.

Comment: why does it print from 0 to 1000 and not from 1000 to 0?

Comment: @VextoR: That's because it first calls f1<N-1>, then prints.

Comment: @VextoR because it's outputting `N` to the console AFTER instantiating the next template.

Comment: @sharptooth <N-1> == 999? Should it print "999" ?

Comment: @VextoR: No, it first calls `f1<999>()`, then prints 1000.

Answer (score 2):

This is not guaranteed to be pure compile-time recursion. The compiler will have to instantiate function `f1()` for all parameters value from 2 to 1000 and they will call each other.

Then the compiler might see that those calls can be just turned into a sequence of `cout << ...` statements. Maybe it eliminates calls, maybe not - this is up to the compiler. From the point of C++ this is a chain of function calls and the compiler can do whatever as long as it doesn't alter behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough, each template instanciation create a new function with the changed parameter. Like if you defined: f1_1000(), f1_999() and so on.

Each function call the function with 1 less in it's name. As there is a different template, not recursive, to define f1_1() we also have a stop case.

Answer (score 1):

You have factorial calculation explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming#Compile-time_class_generation).

btw that a note that your function doesn't work for negative numbers.