# Printing 1 to 1000 without loop or conditionals - in PHP

Tags: php

Idea taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568645/printing-1-to-1000-without-loop-or-conditionals) - this time you can only use PHP. 
Is this even possible?

Comment: echo "1"; echo "2"; .... echo "1000"; :D

Comment: Note that the linked question says *"Don't just write the printf() or cout statement 1000 times."*

Comment: echo is neither printf() nor cout(), it's not even print() :)

Comment: Look at the answers in the original question - there are plenty that aren't using specific language features from C++ and can be translated to PHP easily.

Comment: Does this have any practical purpose?

Comment: @schnaader Compile time methods do not qualify, as long as you don't use compiled PHP :)

Comment: Without something like code_burgar's method, use whatever you like, the machine is going to loop at some point in the end.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's an interesting oo solution based on PHP's overloading:

```
class thousand_printer {
   public function __construct() {
      $this->print1();
   }

   public function __call($method, $_) {
      $count = str_replace('print', '', $method);
      echo "$count ";
      $this->{"print" . ++$count}();
   }

   public function print1000() {
      echo "1000\n";
   }
}

new thousand_printer;
```

I'm glad my solution is so popular.  Here's a slight improvement that offers some modularity:

```
class printer {
   public function __construct() {
      $this->print1();
   }
   public function __call($method, $_) {
      $count = str_replace('print', '', $method);
      echo "$count ";
      $this->{"print" . ++$count}();
   }
}

class thousand_printer extends printer {
   public function print1001() {}
}

new thousand_printer;
```

Answer (score 11):

```
print implode("\n", range(1, 1000));
```

Comment: The reason is to prevent poor quality answers. Not sure it works.

Comment: As if range doesn't use a loop? :)

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php

    class Evil
    {
        function __construct($c) {
            $this->c = $c;
        }

        function __call($name, $args) {
            echo $this->c . "\n";
            $this->c += 1;
            $this->tick();
        }

        // The bomb
        function tick() {
            call_user_func(__NAMESPACE__ .'\Evil::__' . $this->c);
        }

        // 007 
        function __1000() {}
    }

    $devil = new Evil(1);
    $devil->tick();

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple of soltuion with no loop *(not in PHP : it's done by C code ;-) )*, and no conditional :

Using [**`range()`**](https://www.php.net/range) to generate an array, and [**`array_map()`**](http://fr.php.net/array_map) to apply a function to each element :

```
array_map(function ($value) {
    echo "$value<br />";
}, range(1, 1000));
```

Same idea, but using [**`array_walk()`**][3], this time, to apply a function to each element :

```
$array = range(1, 1000);
array_walk($array, function ($value) {
    echo "$value<br />";
});
```

Another *(quite basic, I have to admit, but working ^^* ) idea :

```
echo "1<br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />7<br />8<br />9<br />10<br />11<br />12<br />13<br />14<br />15<br />16<br />17<br />18<br />19<br />20<br />21<br />22<br />23<br />24<br />25<br />26<br />27<br />28<br />29<br />30<br />31<br />32<br />33<br />34<br />35<br />36<br />37<br />38<br />39<br />40<br />41<br />42<br />43<br />44<br />45<br />46<br />47<br />48<br />49<br />50<br />51<br />52<br />53<br />54<br />55<br />56<br />57<br />58<br />59<br />60<br />61<br />62<br />63<br />64<br />65<br />66<br />67<br />68<br />69<br />70<br />71<br />72<br />73<br />74<br />75<br />76<br />77<br />78<br />79<br />80<br />81<br />82<br />83<br />84<br />85<br />86<br />87<br />88<br />89<br />90<br />91<br />92<br />93<br />94<br />95<br />96<br />97<br />98<br />99<br />100<br />101<br />102<br />103<br />104<br />105<br />106<br />107<br />108<br />109<br />110<br />111<br />112<br />113<br />114<br />115<br />116<br />117<br />118<br />119<br />120<br />121<br />122<br />123<br />124<br />125<br />126<br />127<br />128<br />129<br />130<br />131<br />132<br />133<br />134<br />135<br />136<br />137<br />138<br />139<br />140<br />141<br />142<br />143<br />144<br />145<br />146<br />147<br />148<br />149<br />150<br />151<br />152<br />153<br />154<br />155<br />156<br />157<br />158<br />159<br />160<br />161<br />162<br />163<br />164<br />165<br />166<br />167<br />168<br />169<br />170<br />171<br />172<br />173<br />174<br />175<br />176<br />177<br />178<br />179<br />180<br />181<br />182<br />183<br />184<br />185<br />186<br />187<br />188<br />189<br />190<br />191<br />192<br />193<br />194<br />195<br />196<br />197<br />198<br />199<br />200<br />201<br />202<br />203<br />204<br />205<br />206<br />207<br />208<br />209<br />210<br />211<br />212<br />213<br />214<br />215<br />216<br />217<br />218<br />219<br />220<br />221<br />222<br />223<br />224<br />225<br />226<br />227<br />228<br />229<br />230<br />231<br />232<br />233<br />234<br />235<br />236<br />237<br />238<br />239<br />240<br />241<br />242<br />243<br />244<br />245<br />246<br />247<br />248<br />249<br />250<br />251<br />252<br />253<br />254<br />255<br />256<br />257<br />258<br />259<br />260<br />261<br />262<br />263<br />264<br />265<br />266<br />267<br />268<br />269<br />270<br />271<br />272<br />273<br />274<br />275<br />276<br />277<br />278<br />279<br />280<br />281<br />282<br />283<br />284<br />285<br />286<br />287<br />288<br />289<br />290<br />291<br />292<br />293<br />294<br />295<br />296<br />297<br />298<br />299<br />300<br />301<br />302<br />303<br />304<br />305<br />306<br />307<br />308<br />309<br />310<br />311<br />312<br />313<br />314<br />315<br />316<br />317<br />318<br />319<br />320<br />321<br />322<br />323<br />324<br />325<br />326<br />327<br />328<br />329<br />330<br />331<br />332<br />333<br />334<br />335<br />336<br />337<br />338<br />339<br />340<br />341<br />342<br />343<br />344<br />345<br />346<br />347<br />348<br />349<br />350<br />351<br />352<br />353<br />354<br />355<br />356<br />357<br />358<br />359<br />360<br />361<br />362<br />363<br />364<br />365<br />366<br />367<br />368<br />369<br />370<br />371<br />372<br />373<br />374<br />375<br />376<br />377<br />378<br />379<br />380<br />381<br />382<br />383<br />384<br />385<br />386<br />387<br />388<br />389<br />390<br />391<br />392<br />393<br />394<br />395<br />396<br />397<br />398<br />399<br />400<br />401<br />402<br />403<br />404<br />405<br />406<br />407<br />408<br />409<br />410<br />411<br />412<br />413<br />414<br />415<br />416<br />417<br />418<br />419<br />420<br />421<br />422<br />423<br />424<br />425<br />426<br />427<br />428<br />429<br />430<br />431<br />432<br />433<br />434<br />435<br />436<br />437<br />438<br />439<br />440<br />441<br />442<br />443<br />444<br />445<br />446<br />447<br />448<br />449<br />450<br />451<br />452<br />453<br />454<br />455<br />456<br />457<br />458<br />459<br />460<br />461<br />462<br />463<br />464<br />465<br />466<br />467<br />468<br />469<br />470<br />471<br />472<br />473<br />474<br />475<br />476<br />477<br />478<br />479<br />480<br />481<br />482<br />483<br />484<br />485<br />486<br />487<br />488<br />489<br />490<br />491<br />492<br />493<br />494<br />495<br />496<br />497<br />498<br />499<br />500<br />501<br />502<br />503<br />504<br />505<br />506<br />507<br />508<br />509<br />510<br />511<br />512<br />513<br />514<br />515<br />516<br />517<br />518<br />519<br />520<br />521<br />522<br />523<br />524<br />525<br />526<br />527<br />528<br />529<br />530<br />531<br />532<br />533<br />534<br />535<br />536<br />537<br />538<br />539<br />540<br />541<br />542<br />543<br />544<br />545<br />546<br />547<br />548<br />549<br />550<br />551<br />552<br />553<br />554<br />555<br />556<br />557<br />558<br />559<br />560<br />561<br />562<br />563<br />564<br />565<br />566<br />567<br />568<br />569<br />570<br />571<br />572<br />573<br />574<br />575<br />576<br />577<br />578<br />579<br />580<br />581<br />582<br />583<br />584<br />585<br />586<br />587<br />588<br />589<br />590<br />591<br />592<br />593<br />594<br />595<br />596<br />597<br />598<br />599<br />600<br />601<br />602<br />603<br />604<br />605<br />606<br />607<br />608<br />609<br />610<br />611<br />612<br />613<br />614<br />615<br />616<br />617<br />618<br />619<br />620<br />621<br />622<br />623<br />624<br />625<br />626<br />627<br />628<br />629<br />630<br />631<br />632<br />633<br />634<br />635<br />636<br />637<br />638<br />639<br />640<br />641<br />642<br />643<br />644<br />645<br />646<br />647<br />648<br />649<br />650<br />651<br />652<br />653<br />654<br />655<br />656<br />657<br />658<br />659<br />660<br />661<br />662<br />663<br />664<br />665<br />666<br />667<br />668<br />669<br />670<br />671<br />672<br />673<br />674<br />675<br />676<br />677<br />678<br />679<br />680<br />681<br />682<br />683<br />684<br />685<br />686<br />687<br />688<br />689<br />690<br />691<br />692<br />693<br />694<br />695<br />696<br />697<br />698<br />699<br />700<br />701<br />702<br />703<br />704<br />705<br />706<br />707<br />708<br />709<br />710<br />711<br />712<br />713<br />714<br />715<br />716<br />717<br />718<br />719<br />720<br />721<br />722<br />723<br />724<br />725<br />726<br />727<br />728<br />729<br />730<br />731<br />732<br />733<br />734<br />735<br />736<br />737<br />738<br />739<br />740<br />741<br />742<br />743<br />744<br />745<br />746<br />747<br />748<br />749<br />750<br />751<br />752<br />753<br />754<br />755<br />756<br />757<br />758<br />759<br />760<br />761<br />762<br />763<br />764<br />765<br />766<br />767<br />768<br />769<br />770<br />771<br />772<br />773<br />774<br />775<br />776<br />777<br />778<br />779<br />780<br />781<br />782<br />783<br />784<br />785<br />786<br />787<br />788<br />789<br />790<br />791<br />792<br />793<br />794<br />795<br />796<br />797<br />798<br />799<br />800<br />801<br />802<br />803<br />804<br />805<br />806<br />807<br />808<br />809<br />810<br />811<br />812<br />813<br />814<br />815<br />816<br />817<br />818<br />819<br />820<br />821<br />822<br />823<br />824<br />825<br />826<br />827<br />828<br />829<br />830<br />831<br />832<br />833<br />834<br />835<br />836<br />837<br />838<br />839<br />840<br />841<br />842<br />843<br />844<br />845<br />846<br />847<br />848<br />849<br />850<br />851<br />852<br />853<br />854<br />855<br />856<br />857<br />858<br />859<br />860<br />861<br />862<br />863<br />864<br />865<br />866<br />867<br />868<br />869<br />870<br />871<br />872<br />873<br />874<br />875<br />876<br />877<br />878<br />879<br />880<br />881<br />882<br />883<br />884<br />885<br />886<br />887<br />888<br />889<br />890<br />891<br />892<br />893<br />894<br />895<br />896<br />897<br />898<br />899<br />900<br />901<br />902<br />903<br />904<br />905<br />906<br />907<br />908<br />909<br />910<br />911<br />912<br />913<br />914<br />915<br />916<br />917<br />918<br />919<br />920<br />921<br />922<br />923<br />924<br />925<br />926<br />927<br />928<br />929<br />930<br />931<br />932<br />933<br />934<br />935<br />936<br />937<br />938<br />939<br />940<br />941<br />942<br />943<br />944<br />945<br />946<br />947<br />948<br />949<br />950<br />951<br />952<br />953<br />954<br />955<br />956<br />957<br />958<br />959<br />960<br />961<br />962<br />963<br />964<br />965<br />966<br />967<br />968<br />969<br />970<br />971<br />972<br />973<br />974<br />975<br />976<br />977<br />978<br />979<br />980<br />981<br />982<br />983<br />984<br />985<br />986<br />987<br />988<br />989<br />990<br />991<br />992<br />993<br />994<br />995<br />996<br />997<br />998<br />999<br />1000<br />";
```

Using [**`var_export()`**][4], you would also have the numbers from 1 to 1000 displayed -- amongst other things :

```
var_export(range(1, 1000));
```

Using [**`var_dump()`**](http://fr.php.net/var_dump) would get you the same kind of result -- provided Xdebug is either not installed, or properly configured.

Next one, using [**`json_encode()`**][6], to get a more interesting output, that can be re-used in other languages :

```
echo json_encode(range(1, 1000));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
echo implode(' ',range(1, 1000));
```

Comment: always to slow when I bother to test.

Answer (score 4):

Using PHP 5.3 and avoiding `range()`:

```
<?php

    preg_replace_callback('/ /', function() {
        static $i;
        print ++$i."\n";
    }, str_repeat(' ', 1000));

?>
```

PHP just begs to be raped like this.

Comment: preg_replace_callback effectively is a conditional

Comment: Well, everything that compiles down to a conditional jump is effectively a conditional :)

Answer (score 4):

```
function f_0($x) {
    $res = (int)($x/1000);
    print $x;
    $res = "f_".$res;
    $res(++$x);
}

function f_1($y) {
    print $x;
}

f_0(1);
```

Comment: This is the real winner!!

Answer (score 2):

```
$it =  new ArrayIterator(range(1, 1000));
iterator_apply($it, function($it) {
    return print($it->current() . '<br>');
}, array($it));
```

Answer (score 2):

Mine doesn't use range or iterators. It does require PHP 5.3 though.

```
call_user_func( $x = function( $f, $i=1 ) {
  echo "$i\n", $f[floor($i/1000)]($f, ++$i);
}, array( $x, function(){} ));
```

I also posted this to my blog at http://andrewcurioso.com/2011/03/counting-to-1000-in-php-without-loops-or-conditionals/ with an explaination of how it works and a benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

Originally I used `range()`, but since somebody else beat me to it, here's an even worse answer:

```
echo implode("\n", array_keys(array_fill(1, 1000, 0)));
```

Comment: That's THREE loops

Answer (score 1):

An example using recursion, and [**`assert()`**](https://www.php.net/assert) to get out of the recursion :

```
test(1);

function test($i) {
    echo "$i<br />";
    @assert('$i < 1000') || die;
    test($i + 1);
}
```

Well, not sure [**`assert()`**](https://www.php.net/assert) qualifies as *not a condition* ?

Same idea, **if you have Xdebug installed and enabled** -- don't try without Xdebug :

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 1002);

test(1);

function test($i) {
    echo "$i<br />";
    test($i + 1);
}
```

Granted, it'll end up with `Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '1002' reached, aborting!` ; but it'll display all numbers from 1 to 1000 included.

Comment: I'd say `$i < 1000` certainly qualifies as a condition. But the xdebug one is evil. Love it!

Comment: The original question said *"conditional statement"* ; wasn't sure if an `<` **operator** (or any other like it) would count as a *"statement"* ;; still, the xdebug one, I kinda like it too ;-)

Comment: The `<` is a condition, and I would consider the `assert() || die()` to be a glorified if statement, but a cool solution nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

```
<?php

 $no =1;
 HR:
 if($no<1000){
 echo $no++."<br/>";
 goto HR;
 }

?>
```

Comment: Uses a condition

Answer (score 0):

Using [SplFixedArray](http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php) with [RuntimeException](http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/class.runtimeexception.php) (php 5.3):

```
function nextItem ($array) {
    try {
        echo $array->current() . "<br/>\n";
        $array->next();
    } catch (RuntimeException $e) { return; }
    nextItem($array);
}
$a = SplFixedArray::fromArray(range(1, 1000));
nextItem($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my port of my favorite answer from the C/C++ post ( [Printing 1 to 1000 without loop or conditionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568645/printing-1-to-1000-without-loop-or-conditionals/4583502#4583502) ). I'm using variable functions instead of getting pointery.

```
<?php

function f( $j) {

    // two possible return values
    $ret_vals = array("f", "g");

    echo " $j \n ";

    // we're faking a conditional here so that the recursion will
    // bottom out at 1000. This returns f if ($j/1000) is in the
    // interval [0,1) and g if ($j/1000) is in the interval [1,2)
    return $ret_vals[$j/1000]($j+1);
}


// to bottom out the recursion of f()
function g($j) {
    return $j;    
}


f(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. print table without using for loop

```html
<table border="1" >
<?php 
// Print table
echo "<br><br> Table printing here..";
for($x=1;$x<=10;$x++){
 echo "<tr>";

 for($y=1;$y<=12;$y++){
  echo "<td>".$x*$y."</td>";
 }

 echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by using recursive functions "A function call itself". lets create a function numLoop($num):

```
function numLoop($num ){
    if($num > 100){ 
        return false;
    }
    echo $num . '<br>';
    numLoop(++$num);
}

$num = 1;
numLoop($num);
```

Comment: Uses a condition