# How does the C code that prints from 1 to 1000 without loops or conditional statements work?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I've found `C` code that [prints from 1 to 1000 without loops or conditionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568645/printing-1-to-1000-without-loop-or-conditionals/4583502#4583502) : 
But I don't understand how it works. Can anyone go through the code and explain each line?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(int j) {
  printf("%d\n", j);
  (&main + (&exit - &main)*(j/1000))(j+1);
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling as C or as C++? What errors do you see? You cannot call `main` in C++.

Comment: @ninjalj I have created a C++ project and copy/past the code the error are : illegal, left operand has type 'void (__cdecl *)(int)' and 
expression must be a pointer to a complete object type

Comment: @ninjalj These code is working on ideone.org but not in visual studio http://ideone.com/MtJ1M

Comment: @oussama Similar, but slightly _more_ difficult to understand: http://ideone.com/2ItXm  You're welcome. :)

Comment: @Mark good one ,but i don't get the use of # in the first define

Comment: `##` tells the preprocessor to join the things on either side. If I had used `#define MACRONAME blah` and then wrote `somethingMACRONAME`, the preprocessor wouldn't substitute `blah` for `MACRONAME`. However, `something##MACRONAME` would become `somethingblah`. It's explained in more detail under _Advanced Macro Tricks_ at http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cpreprocessor.html

Comment: The mark of any good recursive function is how shallow it stays, and this is as far from good as you can get.

Comment: i have removed all '&' characters from these line (&main + (&exit - &main)*(j/1000))(j+1); and this code still works.

Comment: Do `./prog 2` to have it start with 2 ;-)

Comment: @obounaim if you haven't already figured this out that is because `&`'s are optional in function pointers

Comment: `main + (exit - main)` works because function name is also a function pointer itself. You can even add any number of `*`s to the pointer and it still works: `*main + (*exit - *main)`, `**main + (**exit - **main)`...

Answer (score 267, accepted):

### Don't ever write code like that.

---

For `j<1000`, `j/1000` is zero (integer division). So:

```
(&main + (&exit - &main)*(j/1000))(j+1);
```

is equivalent to:

```
(&main + (&exit - &main)*0)(j+1);
```

Which is:

```
(&main)(j+1);
```

Which calls `main` with `j+1`.

If `j == 1000`, then the same lines comes out as:

```
(&main + (&exit - &main)*1)(j+1);
```

Which boils down to

```
(&exit)(j+1);
```

Which is `exit(j+1)` and leaves the program.

---

`(&exit)(j+1)` and `exit(j+1)` are essentially the same thing - quoting C99 §6.3.2.1/4:

> A function designator is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the
>   operand of the sizeof operator *or the unary & operator*, a function designator with
>   type "**function returning type**" is converted to an expression that has type "**pointer to
>   function returning type**".

`exit` is a function designator. Even without the unary `&` address-of operator, it is treated as a pointer to function. (The `&` just makes it explicit.)

And function calls are described in §6.5.2.2/1 and following:

> The expression that denotes the called function shall have type **pointer to function** returning void or returning an object type other than an array type.

So `exit(j+1)` works because of the automatic conversion of the function type to a pointer-to-function type, and `(&exit)(j+1)` works as well with an explicit conversion to a pointer-to-function type.

That being said, the above code is not conforming (`main` takes either two arguments or none at all), and `&exit - &main` is, I believe, undefined according to §6.5.6/9:

> When two pointers are subtracted, **both shall point to elements of the same array object**, or one past the last element of the array object; ...

The addition `(&main + ...)` would be valid in itself, and could be used, *if* the quantity added was zero, since §6.5.6/7 says:

> For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an
>   array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the
>   type of the object as its element type.

So adding zero to `&main` would be ok (but not much use).

Comment: @Mat i don't get it how to call a function with &

Comment: `foo(arg)` and `(&foo)(arg)` are equivalent, they call foo with argument arg. http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html is an interesting page about function pointers.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra: it's documented in the standards, and it doesn't happen always. For C, it doesn't happen when used in `sizeof` or unary `&`, and for arrays it also doesn't happen when the array is a string literal used to initialize an array (e.g: `char foo[] = "foo"`).

Comment: @ninjalj sorry but char foo[] = "foo" is string literal?  What about char *foo = "foo"

Comment: @Krishnabhadra: `"foo"` is a string literal of type array of char. `char *foo="foo"` has a string literal of type array that gets converted to a pointer to initialize a `char *` variable.

Comment: Anyway I wrote a program like this #include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        char *foo = "foo";
        printf("%u  \n%u \n",foo, &foo);
}
then I got different result as output..

Comment: But when I wrote #include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        char foo[] = "foo";
        printf("%u  \n%u \n",foo, &foo);
}
I got both values equal...

Comment: @Krishnabhadra: in the first case, `foo` is a pointer, `&foo` is the address of that pointer. In the second case, `foo` is an array, and `&foo` is equivalent to foo.

Comment: Unnecessarily complex, at least for C99: `((void(*[])()){main, exit})[j / 1000](j + 1);`

Comment: hmm got that part, but why you said *and for arrays it also doesn't happen when the array is a string literal used to initialize an array (e.g: char foo[] = "foo").*?

Comment: `&foo` is not the same as `foo` when it comes to an array. `&foo` is a pointer to the array, `foo` is a pointer to the first element. They do have the same value though. For functions, `fun` and `&fun` are both pointers to the function.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra: in the `char foo[] = "foo"` case, `foo` gets initialized with _the array_.

Comment: Got that, but what I didn't understand is why you said in this case array name **does not** give array base address? When I print printf("%u",foo); returning the starting address of array..When I print with %s specifier it prints the entire array..So I think you can use array name to get array base address..Thats why I am able to say **char *ptr = foo;** so that pointer will be initialized with the address of the array..

Comment: @Krishnabhadra: err, `char *foo="1234567890"` is a pointer-sized variable that points to an array that is probably in the `.rodata` section. `char foo[] = "1234567890"` is a 11-byte-sized variable. I see where your confusion comes from. `"1234567890"` is also an array.

Comment: *char *foo="1234567890" is a pointer-sized variable that points to an array that is probably in the .rodata section*   100 percent agree...I have nothing to say about this one..

Comment: *"1234567890" is also an array*  hmm..you are right..this part is what confusing me...Ok leave it..This has been going on for too long, on a thread which has its own question and answers...Thanks for your time...I have to read that part of my C book again...

Comment: FYI, if you look at [the relevant answer to the other question cited above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568645/printing-1-to-1000-without-loop-or-conditionals/4583502#4583502), you'll see there's a variation that is in fact comformant C99.  Scary, but true.

Comment: My mind needs clarification - what if I have args? J will start as not 0 and so this will run for less then 1000 iterations, right?

Comment: @Mikle: yes, if you pass in arguments, it won't start at 1. (Note: without args, it would start at 1, not 0, on most implementations - the name of the program itself is passed as the first (zero'eth) element of argv.) But since the `main` declaration, as it is, is not standard (an implementation could make if valid though), YMMV.

Comment: @PerJohansson casting a function pointer to a different type, then calling through that pointer, causes undefined behaviour

Comment: @MattMcNabb the types are compatible. But I agree, it would have been more correct to use `(void(*[])(int))`.

Answer (score 41):

It uses recursion, pointer arithmetic, and exploits the rounding behavior of integer division.

The `j/1000` term rounds down to 0 for all `j < 1000`; once `j` reaches 1000, it evaluates to 1.

Now if you have `a + (b - a) * n`, where `n` is either 0 or 1, you end up with `a` if `n == 0`, and `b` if `n == 1`. Using `&main` (the address of `main()`) and `&exit` for `a` and `b`, the term `(&main + (&exit - &main) * (j/1000))` returns `&main` when `j` is below 1000, `&exit` otherwise. The resulting function pointer is then fed the argument `j+1`.

This whole construct results in recursive behavior: while `j` is below 1000, `main` calls itself recursively; when `j` reaches 1000, it calls `exit` instead, making the program exit with exit code 1001 (which is kind of dirty, but works).

Comment: Good answer, but one doubt..How main exit with exit code 1001? Main is not returning anything..Any default return value?

Comment: When j reaches 1000, main doesn't recurse into itself anymore; instead, it calls the libc function `exit`, which takes the exit code as its argument and, well, exits the current process. At that point, j is 1000, so j+1 equals 1001, which becomes the exit code.

Comment: Actually the exit code will be 233 (1001 % 256 or 1001 & 255).

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7937813/6607497 explains it all, but for the impatient here is the equivalent (readable) code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
void main(int j) {
    printf("%d\n", j);
    if (i/1000 == 0)
        main(j+1);
    else
        exit(j+1);
}
```

So i guess its obvious how it works.
The only real trick being used is the "computed goto" (`&main + (&exit - &main)*(j/1000)`), evaluating to either `main` while `j/1000` is zero, or `exit` otherwise (actually if it's `1`).

Maybe also note that the program is misusing `argc` as `j`, so it will count differently when you pass arguments to the program, and it will most likely crash when you add more than 2000 parameters...