# Why this C++ recursive template didn't work?

Tags: c++, templates, recursion

I found [interesting question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568645) and decided to examine top answer in detail.
I asked myself why there needs structure and try to rewrote the code without it:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
template <int N> void out(std::ostream& os) {
    out<N-1>(os);
    os << N << std::endl;
}

template <> void out<1>(std::ostream& os){
    os << 1 << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    out<100>(std::cout);
}
```

And then I tried to refactor the code.
I got something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
template <int N> void out() {
    if (N != 1) {
        out<N-1>();
        std::cout << N << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    out<100>();
}
```

I don't understand why this code didn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: the branch is a run time construct, the compiler will happily instantiate `out<N-1>` which will carry on... The whole purpose of the specialization is to terminate the instantiations..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `if` condition is evaluated at run-time. When you get to the instantiation where `N = 1`, it doesn't know that the first block of the `if` statement won't execute. It proceeds to instantiate `out<0>` and so on. [If we had a `static if`](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Static-If-I-Had-a-Hammer), this would be possible, but [it probably won't happen very soon](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=forums&srcid=MDIyMDc3NjUwMTczOTM0Mjk3NjABMDI2MzM3MjkxNDM4NDQ5MzE4NDcBLWVsS1Y4dFhtdDhKATUBaXNvY3BwLm9yZwF2Mg).

Answer (score 3):

Templates are expanded during compilation while if statements are only checked during run-time which is a different later stage. In your case the compiler will try to expand indefinetely as there is no specific implementation of the function for a fixed value of N(that used to be `1`).