# Passing non-type parameter agument for templates

Tags: c++, templates

possibly silly question: I am trying to do the following

```
template<unsigned int N>
class Foo{...}; // Define class Foo accordingly

int main(){
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    Foo<i> f(3);
    f.show();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

As you can imagine, it won't compile since the variable `i` is not `const`. I know the reason for this is that the values assigned inside the non-type template argument `Foo<i>` must be known at compile time and since this is not the case here, it doesn't really know what to do. Now, I was wondering if there is a way to overcome this problem. First idea is, of course, to declare `unsigned int N` as member-variable of class Foo.

So question: Is it possible to achieve the desired behaviour above using template arguments, or do I have to declare `unsigned int N` as member variable of my class?

P.S.: I've tried to find a related to question, but the questions I've found were related to how to use non-type template parameters, where they didn't quite answer the question. Since they didn't mention that this is possible I assume this can't be done...

**Edit.**

Is it possible to do the following?

```
template<unsigned int N>
class Foo{...}; // Define class Foo accordingly

int main(){
  std::vector<Foo> v; // I know it's better with shared_ptr, etc.. but to get the idea..
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    Foo<i> f(3);
    f.show();
    v.push_back( f );
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Evg Sorry, didn't mean to. Thanks for making it clear.

Comment: Related: [How to have a const variable in a for loop for the generation of template classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59200748/how-to-have-a-const-variable-in-a-for-loop-for-the-generation-of-template-classe)

Comment: @JeJo, tried to find that one. Thanks for finding it! Still, the container question is not answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't have `for constexpr` in the language, so you can't do it directly. You have to somehow emulate a compile-time `for` loop. There are several options.

1. Use [`std::integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) (C++14) and `int...` pack:

   ```
   template<int i>
   void foo() {
       Foo<i> f(3);
       f.show();
   }

   template<int... is>
   void foo(std::integer_sequence<int, is...>) {
      (foo<is>(), ...);  // expands into foo<0>(), foo<1>(), ..., foo<9>()
   }

   foo(std::make_integer_sequence<unsigned int, 10>{});
   ```
2. Use recursion and `if constexpr` (C++17) to emulate a `for` loop:

   ```
   template<unsigned int i>
   void foo()
   {
       Foo<i> f(3);
       f.show();

       if constexpr (i + 1 < 10)
           foo<i + 1>();
   }

   foo<0>();
   ```
3. Use [`std::integral_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) (C++11) and function overloading:

   ```
   void foo(std::integral_constant<unsigned int, 10>) {}

   template<unsigned int i>
   void foo(std::integral_constant<unsigned int, i>) {
       Foo<i> f(3);
       f.show();
       foo(std::integral_constant<unsigned int, i + 1>{});
   }

   foo(std::integral_constant<unsigned int, 0>{});
   ```

`Foo<i>` and `Foo<j>` are distinct types for distinct `i` and `j`. You can't put distinct types into a `std::vector`. If `i`s are known at compile-time, you can make a `std::tuple` of `Foo<i>`s. But this still would employ some template tricks.

Comment: Hmm. This seems to be pretty complicated. Is it possible to store each instance of class Foo inside of a container (std::vector<Foo>)? Because it seems like your solution is just calling the function show resp. the constructor for different values of i, which is understandable since I didn't state otherwise.

Comment: @ro_go, `Foo<i>`s are distinct types for different `i`s. You can't store different types in a `std::vector`.

Comment: Okay, I should have guessed that you can't put different types into std::vector. Using your first suggestion, how do I get the single elements from the sequence (foo<is>(b), ...)?

Comment: `(foo, ...)` is a sequence of function calls. If you want to put `Foo` into a container to access them later, you can use `std::tuple`.

Comment: So, I guess that using member declarations is easier and more straightforward? Is there any throwback to it?

Comment: @ro_go, if you can make `N` a data member, do it. But this is not always possible. Sometimes you need a template parameter (e.g. to have a data member `std::array<int, N> bar_`), and then you have to resort to template tricks to emulate loops.

Comment: I do not neccessarily need ```N``` as template, but as I am working with basis functions, I thought to give the i-th basis function the template parameter i. Storing it as member variable won't hurt, at the moment