# Is the empty statement in programming languages as C, Java, ... no-op in Assembler?

Tags: programming-languages

A few days ago I saw that `for ( ; ; )` results in an infinite loop. That made me wonder about two things.

1. Is the empty statement ( ; ) no-op in assembler
2. Why is it evaluated as "true" in the for example given above?

Comment: `for` arguments are expressions, not statements.

Comment: you missed a ; at the end of the for :)

Comment: @SK-logic: in my first point I was no longer talking about expressions but about the general case of the empty statement. Sorry for the confusion. x0r: I was just giving an idea, you could also say that I was missing a main function etc. Thanks for the notes in any way.

Comment: @codd, you're missing the difference between statement and expression. Expression yields a value. Statement may (or may not) change the state, but does not return any value. In `for(A;B;C) S`, `A`, `B` and `C` are expressions with default value `1`, `S` is a statement and the whole `for ...` is a statement.

Comment: SK-logic: `f() { ; // this }` I was talking about the empty statement in general as showed in `f()`, have I used the word statement incorrect in this example? Am I correct in saying that in `f()` the empty statement is a statement but in the `for ( ; ; )` it is an expressions?

Comment: @codd, you asked '*why is it evaluated as "true"*' - statement can't be evaluated into a value, only expressions can. See any C standard you can grab a hold of, like, e.g., par. 3.6.5.3 in ANSI C draft: http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering from a C perspective here:

No, `;` does not translate into a no-op *instruction.* No-op instructions (such as `nop`) are explicit assembly level instructions which tend to actually *do* something (in that they consume time, though not necessarily affect any stored state within the CPU).

The `for(;;)` snippet is a `for` loop with defaults for each of the three sections. You can think of the `;` in this case as not being an empty statement but a separator for the sections <sup>(a)</sup>.

- The first section (initialisation) has a default of "do nothing".
- The second section is a condition under which the loop will continue. Its default is to continue forever.
- The third section, the steps to take before beginning a subsequent iteration, is also "do nothing".

I have, in the past, been guilty of the heinous crime of using things like:

```
#define ever ;;
#define forever for (;;)
```

so that I could write my infinite loops as:

```
for(ever) { ... }
forever { ... }
```

I wouldn't do that nowadays of course.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> A "true" empty statement along the lines of:

```
if (condition) {
    a = b;
    ;
}
```

will also probably not translate to a no-op. More than likely it will not result in any code at all.

Keep in mind this is based on fairly common behaviour. In terms of C, `;` can generate any lower level code it wants as long as it doesn't affect the "virtual machine" that is the C environment. It may, for example, increase a hidden line number variable and update coverage statistics if you have profiling enabled.

Comment: Just to augment this answer: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234906/whats-the-purpose-of-the-nop-opcode/235007#235007) is a nice list of other uses for the nop instruction.

Comment: `nop` will normally be only used as a placeholder for debugging.

Comment: I love that forever{...} construct! Although defines may well be a nightmare to debug :D

Comment: Visual Studio seem to have an [`__asm nop; extension`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736275/is-there-asm-nop-equivalent-in-java), and GCC [`asm("nop")`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567220/gcc-nops-being-compiled-away)